# Prove that $n^{1/n}$ is irrational for all $n \in \Bbb Z$ and $n > 1$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, irrational-numbers

Short question:

For all integers $n>1$, is $\sqrt[n]{n}$ always irrational? If so, how can you prove it?

---

Or in other words: is the following true? (And is the typography right?)

$\forall n \ni n \in \mathbb{N},n>1:\sqrt[n]{n} \notin \mathbb{Q}$

*(For all values $n$, such that $n$ is a natural number and larger than 1, the $n^{th}$ root of $n$ is not rational.)*

Comment: The format could also be $$\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>1}, \ \sqrt [n] {n} \notin \mathbb{Q}$$ or for the end part, $$\nexists \frac{p}{q} : \sqrt [n] {n} = \frac{p}{q}, \ (p, q)\in \mathbb{Z} \ \land \ q \neq 0$$.

Comment: Interesting. But for $1= 1^n < n < 2^n$ so $\sqrt[n]{n}$ is not an integer.  It's easy to prove that $\sqrt[n]{k}$ is either an integer or irrational for integer $k$ .  So for $n > 1$ $\sqrt[n]{n}$ is irrational

Comment: side question.  Under what circumstance is $\sqrt[q]q$ rational for rational $q$.  Or $\sqrt[x]x$ rational for real $x$?

Comment: $\sqrt[x]x$ is rational if $\frac1x$ is an integer.

Comment: **Dupe** of [Prove that if $n \geq 2$, then $\sqrt[n]{n}$ is irrational. Hint, show that if $n \geq 2$, then $2^{n} &gt; n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858399/prove-that-if-n-geq-2-then-sqrtnn-is-irrational-hint-show-that-if)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Hint:*

- If $m$ is an integer, then $\sqrt[n]{m}$ is rational iff it is an integer, that is, iff $m$ is an $n$-th power.
- $n$ is never an $n$-th power because $n = t^n > 2^n$ is always false.

Or use that $1 < \sqrt[n]{n} < 2$ implies that $ \sqrt[n]{n} $ is never an integer.