# If $ \sqrt{n}^k$is an integer, then $n \mid\sqrt{n}^k $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Suppose $n$ is an odd integer and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $k \geq 2$. How can I show the following statement?

$$ \sqrt{n}^k \ \text{is an integer}\ \Longrightarrow n \mid\sqrt{n}^k $$

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: It is obviously true when $k$ is even. The case for odd $k$ is only slightly more involved. Neither case seems to need the assumption that $n\ge 3$, they are equally true for $n=0,1,2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p$ a prime dividing $n$. Then $p$ has to be odd. Let $a$ the biggest integer such that $p^a$ divides $n$. Then, we have equivalently to show that 
$$\frac{ak}{2} \in \mathbf{Z} \implies a \le \frac{ak}{2}.$$
Well, the last inequality holds if and only if $k\ge 2$, which is true by assumption.

Answer (score 2):

It is obvious for even $k$.

For odd $k$, we see that the powers of all prime factors of $n$ must be even, i.e, $n$ is a perfect square.

let $n = t^2$.

Therefore the statement boils down to $t^2\mid t^k$ , which is true for all $k\geq 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously $\sqrt{n}^k=n\cdot\sqrt{n^{k-2}}$.

From the hypotheses, $\sqrt{n^{k-2}}$ is an integer. We know that [the square root of a nonnegative integer is either an integer or an irrational number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/sqrt-a-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number). (This is a well-known adaptation of the proof that the square root of two is irrational.) If $\sqrt{n}^k$ is an integer then our equation shows that $\sqrt{n^{k-2}}$ cannot be irrational, so it must be an integer. Therefore $n$ divides $n\cdot\sqrt{n^{k-2}}$ and thus $n$ divides $\sqrt{n}^k$.

Note that this proof does not use the hypothesis that $n$ is odd. It also does not use the hypothesis in the original version of the OP that $n\ge 3$.

Answer (score 2):

$ x = n^{k/2}/n \in \Bbb Q\,\Rightarrow\, x^2 = n^{k-2}\in \Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, x\in \Bbb Z\,$ by the [Rational Root Test.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658006/why-rational-root-theorem-only-works-with-integers/658058#658058) $ $ Thus $\ n\mid n^{k/2}$