# Prove or disprove : $a^3\mid b^2 \Rightarrow a\mid b$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, prime-factorization

I think it's true, because I can't see counterexamples.

Here's a proof that I am not sure of:

Let $p_1,p_2,\ldots, p_n$ be the prime factors of $a$ or $b$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
a&=& p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n} \\
b&=& p_1^{\beta_1}\cdots p_n^{\beta_n} \\
a^3\mid b^2 &&\Rightarrow \frac{b^2}{a^3} \in \mathbb{Z} \\ 
&&\Rightarrow 2 \beta_i - 3\alpha_i \geq 0 \\
&&\Rightarrow 2 \beta_i \geq 3\alpha_i \text{ and } \beta_i \geq 0 \\
&&\Rightarrow 3 \beta_i \geq 3\alpha_i \\
&&\Rightarrow \beta_i \geq \alpha_i \\
&&\Rightarrow \beta_i - \alpha_i \geq 0 \\
&&\Rightarrow \frac{b}{a} \in \mathbb{Z}\\
&&\Rightarrow a\mid b
\end{eqnarray}
Is this proof correct ?

Comment: your proof is correct felicitation!

Comment: Your proof will work if you assume that $a^m|b^n$ and $m\geq n$.

Comment: Why does $\beta_i$ - $\alpha_i$ $\geq$ 0 imply that a|b?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct. Simpler:  $\ a^2\mid a^3\mid b^2\Rightarrow\,(b/a)^2\! = n \in \Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, b/a \in \Bbb Z\,$ by [RRT =  Rational Root Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242).

In detail: if $\,x = b/a\,$ is a root of $\,f(x) = \color{#C00}1\cdot x^2 - n\,$ then RRT implies the least denominator of $\,x\,$ must divide $\color{#c00}1\ (= $  lead coef of $f),\,$ so $\,x\in\Bbb Z,\,$ being a rational writable with denominator $= \color{#c00}1.$

Comment: Note that the case $\,a = 0\,$ is trivial since $\,0\mid n\iff n = 0\ \ $

Comment: Please detail about : 'least denominator of $x$ divides $1$', if possible with example.

Comment: @jiten [RRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242) implies that if $\,f(x)\,$ has rational root $\,b/a\,$(wlog  in lowest terms) then its denom $\,a\,$ divides the lead coef of the polynomial. Here $\,f(x) = \color{#c00}{1}\cdot x^2 - n\,$ has lead coef $= \color{#c00}{1},\,$ thus since $\,a\,$ divides $\,\color{#c00}{1}\,$ we conclude $\,a = 1\,$ (by $\,a>0),\,$ so $\,x = b/a = b/\color{#c00}1\,$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

$a^3|b^2\implies a^2|b^2\implies b^2=a^2k$. Since $a^2k$ is a square we must have $k$ is a square, Since otherwise $\sqrt{a^2k}=a\sqrt k$ which would be irrational. From here $b^2=a^2c^2\implies b=ac\implies a\mid b$

Comment: Correction: $b^2=a^2c^2\,\Rightarrow\, b=\pm ac$.

Comment: but $b,a,c$ are all positive integers.

Comment: It is not given in the original post. It is more general to claim it is true for all integers.