# Prove that if $a, b, n\in \mathbb{N}, n\geq2\longrightarrow \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{a}\in \mathbb{Q} \iff a=b^n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that if $a, b, n\in \mathbb{N}, n\geq2\longrightarrow \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{a}\in \mathbb{Q} \iff a=b^n$.

I'm at a complete loss here, I tried using the order of a prime function but didn't get anywhere. Any tips to get going?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This can be done as a generalization of the proof that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

Comment: The statement is false.  Take $n=2, a=b=4$.  $\sqrt{a}\in \mathbb{Q}$, but $a\neq b^n$.  To make it true, you need to fix the quantifiers.

Comment: @vadim123 this is what the problem says, I'm thinking it should be $\exists b\in \mathbb{N} / \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{a}\in \mathbb{Q} \iff a=b^n$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of the [Rational Root Test.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242) Apply it to the polynomial $\,x^n\!-a.$

Comment: Could you explain a bit? I think I have to use things like FTA to solve this.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD The linked answer gives a proof of RRT which uses well-known consequences of FTA (gcds and Euclid's Lemma).