# prove that $p^{m/n}$, with $p$ prime and $\gcd(m, n)=1$, is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I need to prove that $p^{m/n}$, $m$ and $n$ naturals, $n > 1$, with $p$ prime and $\gcd(m, n)=1$, is irrational. It's suggested that this proof should be by contradiction or contraposition.

Comment: Do you know how to show that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational? Try to generalise that.

Comment: Try a proof by contradiction, assume there is a $p,m,n$ such that $p^{\frac{m}{n}}=\frac{k}{l};k,l \in \Bbb Z$

Comment: It looks like the hypotheses got garbled, Presumably you want $\,n>1, m>0\,$ to exclude obvious counterexamples. I presume that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a comment: the problem should have the hypothesis $m\ne0$ and $n>1$, otherwise the statement is false.

We can assume $m<n$; indeed, with the division algorithm, write $m=nq+r$, with $0\le r<n$. Then
$$
p^{m/n}=p^q\,p^{r/n}
$$
and this is rational if and only if $p^{r/n}$ is rational. It can't be $r=0$, because otherwise $\gcd(m,n)=n>1$.

So we can assume $0<m<n$.

Suppose
$$
p^{m/n}=\frac{a}{b}
$$
for $0<m<n$. Then
$$
b^np^m=a^n
$$
and so $p\mid a^n$, which implies $p\mid a$. Therefore $a=pc$ and
$$
b^np^m=p^nc^n
$$
Since $0<m<n$ we can write this as
$$
b^n=p^{n-m}c^n
$$
and so $p\mid b^n$. Hence $p\mid b$: a contradiction.

Comment: $n>1$ suffices - then $m$ can't be zero if the g.c.d. is 1. I edited the original post to add $n>1$.

Comment: I couldn't figure out why can you assume n > m. I guess I understood the steps of the argument, but I can't see why does it entail the conclusion. Were m > n, everything said would still be true, wouldn't it?
Also, it is fundamental to the proof this assumption?

Comment: @izzorts The assumption just simplifies the proof. If you write $m=nq+r$, then $p^{m/n}=p^qp{r/n}$. Since $p^q}$ is rational, we just need to show $p^{r/n}$ is irrational.

Comment: I tried to do it without supposing $n$ > $m$. Suppose $p^{m/n}$ rational. So $p^{m/n}$ = $a/b$ ($gdc(a, b) = 1$). Also suppose $n$ > 1, otherwise it's trivial that $p^{m/n}$ is an integer or undefined. Now take $p^{m}$ = $a^{n}/b^{n}$. Then $a^{n}$ = $b^{n}p^{m}$. Therefore $p$ divides $a^{n}$ and consequently $a$. So $a$ = $pk$ for a $k$ in N. So $p^{m}$ = $p^{n}k^{n}/b^{n}$, and it follows that $b^{n} = p^{n-m}k^{n}$. Now, if $n$ > $m$, it implies that $p$ also divides $b$, contradicting $gdc(a, b) = 1$. Else, being $m$ > $n$, we have $b^{n} = k^{n}/p^{m-n}$.

Comment: Then $b=k/p^{{(m−n)}/n}$ = $k/p^{m/n}p^{−1}$ = $pk/p^{m/n}$ Ergo $b$ is divisible by $p$ in this case also, implying the same contradiction. So assuming $p^{m/n}$ rational implies contradiction in all cases possible.

Comment: @izzorts You are using $p^{m/n}$ in the last part, which is only supposed to be rational, not integer.

Comment: I don't see where I assumed it to be an integer, or when it were necessary to the argument, could you show me specifically, please?

Comment: @izzorts You use it when from $b=pk/p^{m/n}$ you deduce $p$ divides $b$.

Comment: Alright, thanks, now I see it. Anyway, any tips on how would I prove this last part without assuming $n > m$, then?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\,p^{m/n}$ is rational. It's a  root of $\,x^n\! = p^m$ so by the [Rational Root Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242) $\,x\,$ is an integer $\,a.$ Therefore, $ $ comparing powers of $\,p\,$ in $\,a^n = p^m$ $\Rightarrow$ $\,n\alpha = m\,$ so $\,n\mid m\,$ contra $\,n,m\,$ coprime.

**Remark** $ $ Without RRT: $\ $ if $\ p^{m/n}\! = a/b\ $ is rational then $\, p^m b^n = a^n\,$ hence comparing powers of $\,p\,$ on both sides of the prior equation yields  $\, m+n\beta = n\alpha\, $ so $\, n\mid m\, $ contra $\,n,m\,$ coprime

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to prove that
$p^{m/n}$
is irrational,
you have to assume that
it is rational
and derive a contradiction.

So,
assume that
$p^{m/n}
= \frac{a}{b}
$
where
$(a, b) = 1$.

Then
$p^{m}
= \frac{a^n}{b^n}
$
or
$b^np^{m}
= a^n
$.

$p$ must divide $a$,
so let
$a = p^kq$
where
$p \not\mid q$.
Since
$(a, b) = 1$,
$p \not\mid b$.
Then
$b^np^{m}
= a^n
= (p^k q)^n
= p^{kn} q^n
$.

Since $p$ does not divide
either of
$b$ and $q$,
$m = kn$,
so that
$n \mid m$.
Since
$(m, n) = 1$,
this implies that
$n = 1$,
which is the
only way that
$p^{m/n}$
is rational.

And we are done.

Answer (score -3):

Assume the negation of the statement and set out for a contradiction. That is $$\frac{k}{l}^{\frac{n}{m}}=p$$

But the greatest common denominator is one so

$$\frac{k^{\frac{n}{m}}}{l^{\frac{n}{m}}}$$

Which must be a multiple of $l^{\frac{n}{m}}$. So $p=j^{\frac{n}{m}}$.

$p=({g^{\frac{1}{m}}})^n$ which contradicts the fact that $p$ was prime.