# Rational root theorem

Tags: polynomials, rational-numbers

In a Complex Analysis course I'm asked to show that the rational root theorem is true, stated as follows.

> Show that the following holds true: Let the real rational number $p/q$
>   (where $p$ and $q$ have no common factor except $\pm 1$ be a solution
>   of $$a_n z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 z + a_0 = 0, \quad a_j
>  \in \mathbb{Z}.$$ Then $q$ must be a factor of $a_n$ and $p$ must be a
>   factor of $a_0$.

Now, for $n=1$, I can show $p = a_0\frac{-a_1}{q}$ and $q = a_1\frac{-a_0}{p}$.

For $n = 2$, we have $p = \frac{q}{2a_2}(-a_1 \pm \sqrt{a_1^2-4a_2a_0}) =^{?} a_0 (\ldots).$

I suppose we need to somehow use that  $a_j \in \mathbb Z$ and $p,q \in \mathbb Z$.

Furthermore, the exercise asks me to *show*, rather than to *prove*. But still, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: "Show" and "prove" more or less mean the same thing.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I find it quite a non-trivial exercise, in that case.

Comment: You can find a proof here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658006/why-rational-root-theorem-only-works-with-integers

Comment: I'm trying to avoid **looking at the proof**. First I want to try it myself, can you give a hint?

Comment: Write the equation as $(a_n z^{n-1} + a_{n-1}z^{n-2} + \ldots + a_1)z = -a_0.$ Plug in $p/q$ and multiply by $q^n$. (This will give you soon one of the two claims the other is similar.)

Comment: @quid Was your argument in line with considering the divisors of the LHS and the RHS, or where you using something else?

Comment: @MusséRedi it's the argument in the answer. You could also have followed the link now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z = p/q$ is a rational root $$a_n z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 z + a_0 = 0$$ reads $$a_n \frac{p^n}{q^n} + \ldots + a_1 \frac{p}{q} + a_0 = 0$$ which multiplied by $q^n$ gives $$a_n p^n + a_{n-1}q p^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 p q^{n-1} = - a_0 q^n$$

As $p$ divides the lefthand side, p divides the righthand one, and by hypothesis, as $p$ and $q$ cannot have other common factors than $\pm 1$, $p$ divides $a_0$.

But we can also write

$$- a_n p^n = a_{n-1}q p^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 p q^{n-1} +a_0 q^n$$ so that $q$ dividing the righthand side divides also the lefthand one, and as $p$ and $q$ cannot have other common factors than $\pm 1$, $q$ divides $a_n$.

Comment: Excellent. The argument of considering $p$ and $q$ as divisors of equations is very neat.

Comment: @MusséRedi It is worth emphasizing that this proof depends crucially on FTA =  fundamental theorem of arithmetic (existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations), even though that is not explicitly stated. Normally one deduces those divisibilities by using consequences of FTA such as Euclid's Lemma $\,(\gcd(a,b)=1,\ a\mid bc\,\Rightarrow\,a\mid c)\,$ or closely related results. Without such fundamental results the Rational Root Test need not hold, e.g. it may fail in rings of algebraic integers.