# Show that polynomial is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility, irreducible-polynomials

My teacher solved the following problem:

Find out if the polynomial $F(X) = X^3+3X+2$ is irreducible or reducible over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

His proof was the following one: The root of the polynomial are of form $\frac{a}{b}$.

$F\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^3 + 3\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) + 2 = 0  $ | ( we multiply by $b^3$)

$a^3 +3ab^2 +2b^3 = 0 $

$a^3+b^2(3a+2b) = 0 $

From here he deduced that $b\mid  a^3$ and that $a \mid 2$. How did he find this out? Why is this true? From this he further stated that $b=\pm1$ and $a=\pm2$.

Can someone help me out with the deduction that $b \mid a^3$ and $a\mid 2$?

Comment: That proof is a special case of the proof of the well-known  [Rational Root Test.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8721/242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you know from the very beginning that $b \mid a$ since the polynomial is monic and $\mathbb Z$ is integral closed in $\mathbb Q$.

But let's deduce your statements from $a^3 + b^2(3a+2b) = 0$. This equation implies that $a^3$ and $b^2(3a+2b)$ differ only by a sign, so they have the same factors. Since $b$ is a factor of $b^2(3a+2b)$ it has also to be a factor of $a^3$, so $b \mid a^3$.

We can assume $a$ and $b$ to be coprime (by reducing the fraction $a/b$). So $b \mid a^3$ implies $b= \pm 1$. So $a/b \in \mathbb Z$, so without loss of generality $b=1$. Hence $a$ is a root of the polynomial and $(X-a)$ is a factor of the polynomial. The constant terms of $F/(X-a)$ and $X-a$ have to multiply to $2$, so $a \mid 2$.

$F(X) \ge 2$ for $X \ge 0$. So $a \in \{-1,-2\}$. Evaluating gives $a=-2$.

Comment: Can you further explain why $F/(X-a)$ and $X-a$ have to multiply to 2?

Comment: Is it because roots divide the free term of the polynomial ?

Comment: Yup,got it! Thank you for the help!

Comment: Given that the OP is struggling with basic divisibility inferences, it makes little sense to begin with mention of more advanced concepts such as integral closure. It would be more appropriate to mention more elementary instances such as the Rational Root Test.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use the [rational root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)? If yes, then $a\mid 2$ and $b\mid 1$. A proof can be found here on MSE, e.g., at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903619/rational-root-theorem). In any case, it may be useful for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is as follow:
$$X^3+3X+2=(X-a)(X^2+bX-c); a,b,c\in\mathbb Z\iff\begin{cases}c+a^2=- 3\\ac=2\end{cases}$$ The only integer solutions for $ac=2$ are not compatible with $c+a^2=-3$.

Thus $F(X)$ is irreducible.