# Concerns with the proof of the rational root theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I have to solve the following exercise:

Let $R$ be a unique factorization domain and $f \in R[x]$ a polynomial with leading coefficient $a_n$ and constant coefficient $a_0$. Furthermore $p,q \in R$ coprime with $f(\frac{p}{q})=0$. Prove $p\vert a_0$ and $q\vert a_n$.

I have seen the proofs on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and in this thread [Rational root theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903619/rational-root-theorem).

I understand the arguments but my concern is am I allowed to multiply with $q^n$ and shorten the fractions in an UFD? Especially what means $ \frac{p}{q}$ in a UFD? 
My guess was that this is an element of the quotientfield in it's unique reduced representation. But isn't this mixing of elements of different types then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rational root theorem for UFDs is this:

> Let $D$ be a UFD. Let $K$ be its field of fractions. Let $p/q \in K$, with $p,q \in D$ coprime, 
>   be a solution of a polynomial equation over $D$:
>   $$a_n z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 z + a_0 = 0$$
>   Then $q$ must divide $a_n$ and $p$ must divide $a_0$.

The proof is the same as for $D=\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my algebra course we introduced the quotient field of  an integral domain $R$ via an equivalence relation $\equiv$ so $K$ would be $K=R\times R^\times / \equiv$. So the elements in the quotient field are equivalence classes and the coefficients of the polynomial are elements in $R$. Why can I mix multiply them?

Comment: @thehardyreader, there is a natural embedding of $D$ into $K$, and so we may assume $D \subseteq K$. Focus not on what things *are* but rather on *how they behave*.

Comment: ah okay! yes that is clear to me. so I should see the coefficients as elements  in $K$ rather then as elements of $R$ (or $D$ if you prefer).

Comment: @thehardyreader, if it makes you feel better, write "Let $K$ be a field containing $D$" instead.

Comment: okay, thanks for your help!