# How to prove that when $m$ is not a full power of any natural number, then $m^{(1/2) }$ is irrational

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> How to prove that when $m$ is not a full power of any natural number, then $m^{(1/2) }$ is irrational

I have tried this but got nothing;

$\sqrt{m}=\frac{p}{q}$ were $p,q$ are natural and $\gcd(p,q)=1$;

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/sqrt-a-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number

Answer (score 3):

From $\sqrt m=\frac ab$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$, we find $a^2=mb^2$. Let $p$ be a prime dividing $b$. Then $p\mid mb^2=a^2$, hence also $p\mid a$. This contradicts $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Hence no such prime exists. We conclude $q=1$.

Comment: This proof if *exactly* a special case of the proof of [the Rational Root Test](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242) applied to $\,x^2 - m.\,$ If one already knows this test then is is simpler to invoke it by name (vs. repeat the proof in this special case).

Comment: Should we assume on the beginning that b must be different from 1