# Prove that $\frac{pq}{r}+\frac{qr}{p}+\frac{pr}{q}\in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, \frac{pq}{r},\frac{qr}{p},\frac{pr}{q}\in\Bbb Z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $p,q,r$ be integers such that the symmetric sum of fractions $\dfrac{pq}{r}+\dfrac{qr}{p}+\dfrac{pr}{q}$ is an integer.

Prove that each of the numbers: $\dfrac{pq}{r},\dfrac{qr}{p},\dfrac{pr}{q}$ is an integer.

How to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ The hypothesis implies $\,\large {\big(x-\frac{pq}r\big)\big(x-\frac{qr}p\big)\big(x-\frac{pr}q\big)}\,$ has *all integer* coefficients, therefore the [Rational Root Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242) implies that its rational roots are integers.

Comment: is " Rational Root Test implies that its rational roots are integers" true only when leading coefficient is $1$, and which is with our question ($x^3$)?

Comment: @Ayush Yes, if the leading coefficient is $\,c\,$ then RRT implies that the denominator $\,d\,$  of a least-terms rational root must divide $c$.  Only the *monic* case $\,c = \pm1.\,$ has a *unique* positive divisor $(= 1),\, $  since *all* positive divisors $d$ of $c$ can occur as a  denominator, e.g. $\,(dx-1)(ex^{n-1}-1)\,$ has root $\,x = 1/d.\ $

Comment: @Num If $\,x^3+bx^2+cx+d\,$ has *all* integer coefficients then every rational root is an integer, by RRT..

Comment: @Num All the *rational* roots are integral (this is vacuously true.when it has no rational roots).