# Prove $\, \frac{ab}{c}+ \frac{ac}{b}+ \frac{bc}{a}\in\Bbb Z \,\Rightarrow\, \frac{ab}{c},\frac{ac}{b},\frac{bc}{a}\in\Bbb Z $

Tags: proof-explanation, contest-math, roots, integers, cubics

Prove $\, \frac{ab}{c}+ \frac{ac}{b}+ \frac{bc}{a}\in\Bbb Z \,\Rightarrow\, \frac{ab}{c},\frac{ac}{b},\frac{bc}{a}\in\Bbb Z $

Problem:
Let $a,b,c$ be three integers for which the sum
$ \frac{ab}{c}+ \frac{ac}{b}+ \frac{bc}{a}$
is integer.
Prove that each of the three numbers
$ \frac{ab}{c}, \quad \frac{ac}{b},\quad \frac{bc}{a} $
is integer.

(Proposed by Gerhard J. Woeginger)

The solution is as follows:
Set $u := ab/c, v := ac/b$ and $w := bc/a$. By assumption, $u + v + w$ is an integer. It is easily
seen that $uv + uw + vw = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ and $uvw = abc$ are integers, too.
According to Vieta’s formulæ, the rational numbers $u, v, w$ are the roots of a cubic polynomial
$x^3 + px^2 + qx + r$ with integer coefficients. As the leading coefficient is 1, these roots are integers.

Question: I haven't found anything supporting this, but why does a cubic equation with integer coefficients and a leading coefficient of 1 have integer roots? Why does the cubic equation $x^3+5x^2-20x+5=0$ not have integer roots then?

Comment: **Dupe** of [$\frac{pq}{r}+\frac{qr}{p}+\frac{pr}{q}\in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, \frac{pq}{r},\frac{qr}{p},\frac{pr}{q}\in\Bbb Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110555/fracpqr-fracqrp-fracprq-in-bbb-z-rightarrow-fracpqr-fr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It follows from the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) that every *rational* root of every monic polynomial (of any degree) with integer coefficients must be integer.

Besides, the polynomial $x^3+5x^2-20x+5$ has no rational roots.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).