# Does $ \sum_{i=1}^n n^{k_i} $ determines $(k_1,...,k_n)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, power-series

Let $k_1,...,k_n\in\mathbb{N}$. Does the power sum
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n n^{k_i}
$$
uniquely determines the $n$-tuple $(k_1,...,k_n)$?

**Remark**: In the case $n=2$, this is true. However, when trying to generalize to an arbitrarily sized sum, it doesn't hold. For example,
$$
2^0+2^0+2^2=2^1+2^1+2^1.
$$
I then thought of a fixed sum size, equal to the considered base, but I don't know exactly how to argue or build this bijection. The motivation behind this question comes from trying to determine the $n$-tuple $(k_1,...,k_n)$ from the sum
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n g(k_i),
$$
where $g$ is some constructible function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously you can only hope to determine the $n$-tuple up to permutation, and you can only hope to determine even that when $n>1$. So I'll assume that's what you want. And as you see, it doesn't work in general when the number of $k_i$ is not equal to the base of the exponent.

Then the answer is yes, if you know $n$. It's a corollary of the uniqueness of base-$n$ representations. You can read off the $k_i$ from the digits of the number $s = \sum_{i=1}^n n^{k_i}$ written base $n$. The $j^{\small\text{th}}$ digit ($j=0$ is the first digit) will tell you how many $k_i$ are equal to $j$, unless there is exactly one $1$ and no other nonzero digits in $s$, in which case all the $k_i$ are equal to $j-1$ where $j$ is the place where the $1$ occurs.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this corollary?

Comment: What if all the $k_i=k$ for som $k$, then $s=n^{k+1}$ and it is no longer true that "The $j$th digit will tell you how many $k_i$ are equal to $j$". Should we use base $n+1$ instead?

Comment: @samwolfe The answer already covers that special case. If the number is of the form $(100\!\ldots\!0)_n$, i.e. if it's a perfect power of $n$, then all the $k_i$ are equal. In all other cases, you can just read the digits directly.

Comment: Ah, I see now. So I suppose in that case, we can simply construct the list $\{k_1,...,k_n\}$ by taking the constant array where $k=\log_n(s)-1$, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Adding more details.

Let $a_j$ be the number of the exponents that are equal to $j$. I.e.
$$
a_j = \#\{i \mid k_i=j\}.
$$
We have
$$S:=\sum_{i=1}^n n^{k_i} = \sum_{j\ge0}a_jn^j.$$
**Case 1 - Not all of the exponents are equal:** Then $0\le a_j<n$ for all $j$. Thus the sequence $(a_0, a_1, \ldots)$ is the base $n$ representation of $S$.

**Case 2 - All of the exponents are equal:** Say $k_i=j$ for all $i$. Then $S=n^{j+1}$.

Note crucially this: Numbers in case 1 have different base $n$ representations (by uniqueness of such representations). Also, no number can be in both cases, again by uniqueness: If $S$ is a perfect power of $n$ (case 2), then it only has one non-zero digit base $n$, so it can't be in case 1.

Therefore we have a strategy: Write $S$ in base $n$. If there is more than one non-zero digit, read off the digits as the unique answer for the exponents. Otherwise, $S$ must be a perfect power of $n$, say equal to $n^{j+1}$. Then all exponents are equal to $j$.