# $\frac{a^{3}+1}{b+1}+\frac{b^{3}+1}{a+1}$ an integer $\Rightarrow \frac{a^{3}+1}{b+1}$ and $\frac{b^{3}+1}{a+1}$ are integers.

Tags: number-theory

I want to show that if the natural numbers $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ are such that $\frac{a^3+1}{b+1}+\frac{b^3+1}{a+1} \in \mathbb{N}$, then, necessarily, $\frac{a^3+1}{b+1} \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\frac{b^3+1}{b+1} \in \mathbb{N}$.

I have thought the following.

We are given that $\frac{a^3+1}{b+1}+\frac{b^3+1}{a+1} \in \mathbb{N}$.

This means that $\frac{a^3+1}{b+1}+\frac{b^3+1}{a+1}=k, \text{ for some } k\in \mathbb{N}$.

We also have that $b+1 \mid a^3+1$ and $a+1 \mid b^3+1$, right?

So does it suffice to reject the cases that $a^3+1=k_1(b+1)$ and $b^3+1=k_2 (a+1)$ for negative $k_1, k_2$ ? If so, then we pick all the possible combinations and want to get a contradiction from the fact that $\frac{a^3+1}{b+1}+\frac{b^3+1}{a+1} \in \mathbb{N}$, or not?

Or do we show somehow else that $\frac{a^3+1}{b+1} \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\frac{b^3+1}{b+1} \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: You can't go from $\frac{w}{x}+\frac{y}{z}\in\mathbb{N}$ to $x|w$ and $z|y$. You're implicitly assuming that $\frac{w}{x}$ and $\frac{y}{z}$ are integers when you go through that step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\ r\! +\! s,\, rs \in \Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, r,s \in \Bbb Z\ $ by applying the [Rational Root Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242) to $\,(x\!-\!r)(x\!-\!s)\in\Bbb Z[x]$

Comment: If the hint is too terse I can elaborate. Let me know.

Comment: Yes, could you please explain it further to me? I haven't understood how we apply the Rational Root Test? @BillDubuque

Comment: Applying the Rational Root test to $(x-r)(x-s)$, we deduce that the only roots are the divisors of $rs$. Right? How does this help? @BillDubuque

Comment: @Evinda RRT implies that if a polynomial with integer coef's is *monic* (lead coef $= 1$) then every rational root is an integer, because the denominator of any reduced rational root must divide the lead coef.  This is a fundamental fact used widely in number theory and algebra.

Comment: From your last mentioned statement, we have that all the roots of the polynomial $x^2-(r+s)x+rs$ are integers. And we also have that the roots are divisors of $rs$, right? Two possible divisors of $rs$ are $r$ and $s$, and so we have that $r$ and $s$ are integers, right? @BillDubuque

Comment: Or is it possible that we have a solution other than $r$ or $s$ and so my above statemnt is wrong?

Comment: @Evinda $r,s$ are roots of $(x-r)(x-s)= x^2-(r+s)x + rs$.  Choosing $r,s$ as your summands completes the proof since they have integer sum and product.

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot :) @BillDubuque

Comment: @Evinda Great!  Please feel welcome to ask further questions if need be. It is not unusual to be puzzled when one first encounters these pretty applications of RRT.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can prove this more general statement:

> Let $w,x,y,z$ be positive integers so that
>
> $$\frac{w}{x}+\frac{y}{z}\in\mathbb{N}$$
>
> and $z|w,x|y$. Then
>
> $$\frac{w}{x},\frac{y}{z}\in\mathbb{N}.$$

To do so, consider $d=\gcd(x,z)$, which must divide each of $w$ and $y$, so by dividing each variable by $d$ it suffices to consider the case where $\gcd(x,z)=1$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Why does $d=gcd(x,z)$ divide $w$ and $y$ ? @CarlSchildkraut

Comment: If we have that $z|w$ and $x|y$, then $d|z|w$ and $d|x|y$ for $d=\gcd(x,z)$.

Comment: Ok, I see.. But how do we proceed after considering that gcd(x,z)=1 ?

Comment: Consider what happens if $x\nmid w$ or $z\nmid y$. What would have to be in the denominator of the other term?

Comment: Do we then set $w=\lambda x+k$ for $k \neq 0$ ? Then $\frac{w}{x}+\frac{y}{z}=\lambda+\frac{k}{x}+\frac{y}{z}$. Can we get somehow that the latter is not a natural number? Or do we have to do something else?

Comment: @Evinda Above is a special case of the fact that rationals who sum and product are integers must themselves be integers, by  RRT = Rational Root Test, see my answer. RRT is the *master theorem* for problems like this. Learn it well.

Comment: @BillDubuque I haven't really understood how we can deduce from the rational root test that $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I am also wondering how can we finish the proof with the way you used. Can you give me a hint how we continue?

Comment: @Evinda Assume $\frac{w}{x}$ reduces to $\frac{m}{n}$, where $n>1$. Then $\frac{y}{z}$ must reduce to $\frac{m'}{n}$, where $n|m+m'$. However, we have that $n|x$ and $n|z$, so...

Comment: Why does then $\frac{y}{z}$ have to be reduced to $\frac{m'}{n}$ where $n \mid m+m'$ ?

Comment: @Evinda because it is an integer minus $m/n$.

Comment: Ah, I see. So since $n \mid x$ and $n \mid z$, we also have that $n \mid gcd(x,z)=1 \Rightarrow n=1$, which is a contradiction. Right?

Comment: @Evinda Yes, that's correct!