# Does $f(x)=x^3+x^2-8x+1$ have rational roots?

Tags: polynomials, roots, rational-numbers

### Problem

Does $f(x)=x^3+x^2-8x+1$ have rational roots ?

### Attempt to solve

A citation from our lecturer

*Possible rational roots are in form of:*

$$ \frac{\text{factor of constant}}{\text{factor of highest degree}} $$

now if i would rewrite equation so that factor of every degree is visible:

$$ f(x)=(1) \cdot x^3+(1) \cdot x^2 + (-8) \cdot x + (1)\cdot 1 $$

$$ \text{factor of constant} = 1 $$
$$ \text{factor of highest degree} = 1 $$
$$ \implies \frac{1}{1} = 1 \neq 0 \implies \text{"no rational roots"}$$

However the example solution for this problem suggests that $1$ and $-1$ are factors but i cannot see how. If you would use $-1$ as factor it would change the polynomial in to another one. It claims that constant and highest degree factor have $-1$ as factor in common but i cannot see how.

Another thing is i don't quite get how this implies this polynomial doesn't have any rational roots ? If someone could provide an explanation on what's going on, that would be great.

Comment: This follows from Vieta's theorem. The product of all roots is equal to constant divided by coefficient of the highest degree.

Comment: @Vanya Not true, the proofs requires more structure than that, e.g. the existence of gcds, e.g. see [this proof.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method described by your lecturer says that **if** the polynomial has rational roots, **then** these roots can be obtained by a certain process. Since that process provides no rational roots, the conclusion is that $f(x)$ has no rational roots.

And what's so strange about the fact that $f(x)$ has no rational roots. The roots of $x^2-2$ are $\pm\sqrt2$, which are irrational. Therefore, $x^2-2$ has no rational root. What's supposed to be the problem?

Comment: The problem is i don't think i quite understand on how this process for obtaining the roots works.  Or more specifically why does it work ?

Comment: See the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem#First_proof).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach: $x^3+x^2-8x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$.
 In particular it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, so it has no rational roots.