# Is a domain integrally-closed if root-closed $[(a/b)^n\!\in A\Rightarrow a/b\in A]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I know that $x \in$ Frac($A$), $x^n \in A$ for some integer $n>0$, does not imply that  $x \in A$, as the example in the comments shows.

This leads me to the following question: is $A$ integrally closed if $x \in$ Frac($A$), $x^n \in A$ for some integer $n>0 \Rightarrow x \in A$.

Comment: In $A = \Bbb Z[\sqrt 8]$ we have  $(\sqrt 8/2)^2 = 2$ and $\,\sqrt8/2\not\in A\ \ $

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2969641/242) more generally.

Comment: Thats much easier than i thought. I've edited the question, do you have any counter example for this one @BillDubuque

Comment: Please add some context / effort to the question else it will likely be closed and deleted.

Comment: I added your prior remarks to the question so that it has some context (without such some users will close and delete it), Please update as need be.

Comment: i don't get it, why does my effort needed, i just wish someone show me some way to construct weird rings. And im not familiar with that. Is this place only for helping with homeworks.

Comment: The politics of the site is complicated and cannot be summarized in a comment. You can learn more by perusing meta, e.g. try [this search](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=context) for a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the original question: in $A = \Bbb Z[\sqrt 8]$ we have  $(\sqrt 8/2)^2 = 2$ and $\,\sqrt8/2\not\in A\ \ $

For the update: let's recall some definitions that are "root" (radical) analogs of [integral closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element).

If $D$ is a domain with fraction-field $K$ then $D$ is *$n$-root closed* if $\,x\in K,\, x^n \in D\Rightarrow x\in D$

$D$ is *root-closed*  if it is $n$-root closed for all $\,n\ge 1$.

It's not hard to determine which quadratic number rings are root closed, e.g. we have the following result, which is Corollary $2.2$ [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00013-002-8268-3#).

**Theorem** $ $   A non-integrally closed algebraic order $R$ with conductor $I$ is root closed $\iff I\,$ is an intersection of maximal ideals $\,P_i\,$ of $\,\bar R = $ integral closure of $R$, such that $|\bar R/P_i| = 2$ for each $P_i$

As they remark: in the quadratic case this yields $R=\Bbb Z[\sqrt d]$ is root-closed $\iff d\,$ is square-free and either $\,d\equiv 2,3\pmod{\!4}\,$ or $\,d\equiv 1\pmod{\!8}.\,$ In the first case is $R$  integrally closed. The second case is the only non-integrally closed case satisfying the conditions of the Theorem. In fact, $\,2\,$ decomposes in $\bar R\,$ and $\,2\bar R\,$ is the conductor of $R,$ an intersection of two maximal ideals $P_i$ of $\bar R$ with $|\bar R/P_i| = 2\,$ for $i = 1, 2.$

There is much prior work on root-closure (and the closely related notion of *seminormal*, i.e. $\,x\in K,\, x^2,x^3\in D\Rightarrow x\in D)\,$ - much of which can be located by chasing citations starting with the linked paper.