# GCD and LCM number theory problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I am having some trouble finishing a solution to this problem, so I thought I might ask you all for help.

The problem goes as follows:
Find all natural numbers $a,b>0$ for which holds:

$$lcm(x,y)-gcd(x,y)=\frac{xy}{2021}$$

The problem is annoted with the hint, that 2021=43*47.

I have tried using the fact, that the $gcd=d$ from which follows $x=a*d$ and $y=b*d$. The $lcm(x,y)$ therefore must be $lcm(x,y)=a*b*d$.
Given this and the fact that the product of two numbers $x,y$ and their $gcd$ and $lcm$ is the same, meaning
$$xy=lcm(x,y)*gcd(x,y)=abd*d$$ I arrive at the equation:

$$(abd)-d=(abd^2)/2021$$
which equals
$$2021(ab-1)=abd$$

Where do I go from here? Any help or correction of mistakes that I may have made is greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe use that $ab$ and $ab-1$ are coprime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rewrite it as $(2021 - d)ab = 2021$. Now use the factorization of $2021$ given in the hint.

Comment: I have been trying this approach, but am still not getting anything. Do I need to guess for which range numbers this could be true, or am I completely missing something?

Comment: The product of three integers is equal to $2021$. Since $2021 = 43 \times 47$, there are not many choices. Essentially there are only two possibilities: $1 \times 43 \times 47$ and $1\times 1\times 2021$. And you should consider different permutations of the factors.

Comment: Wouldn't that leave no possible solutions? Given that problems like this normally do have at least one solution that makes me think I am getting something wrong. So can you give me a hint as to whether there are solutions and I am getting something wrong?

Comment: Why do you think there are no solutions? We may have e.g. $a = 43, b = 47, 2021 - d = 1$ (and some more).

Comment: Oh yes you are right! I kept mistaking $a$ and $b$ for $x$ and $y$ and therefore wrongly thought that $d$ could not be bigger than $a$ and $b$. Thanks for the quick answers!

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Let $(x,y)=d$ and WLOG $x/a=y/b=d\implies(a,b)=1$

$$abd-d=\dfrac{abd^2}{2021}$$

$$\iff\dfrac{2021(ab-1)}{ab}=d$$

But $2021=43\cdot47$

So, $a,b\in[1,43,47,2021]$

Can you take it home from here?

Answer (score -1):

Hint: write it as $\,f(a)=0\,$ so $\,a\mid f(0)\,$ since $\,f\,$ is a *polynomial* in $\,a\,$ with *integer* coef's. Thus the integer values that $a$ can take are constrained to the *finite* number of factors of $\,f(0)\,$ (if $\,f(0)\neq 0)$

**Remark** $ $ This can be viewed as special (trivial) case of the ubiquitous [Rational Root Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242), i,e., an integer root of $f$ divides its constant term.