# Is there a polynomial $f\in \mathbb Q[x]$ such that $f(x)^2=g(x)^2(x^2+1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, rational-numbers

I was asked the following question:

$g\in \mathbb Q[x]$ is a polynomial (not the zero polynomial).

Find $f \in \mathbb Q[x]$ such that $f(x)^2=g(x)^2(x^2+1)$ or show that such an $f$ does not exist.

I really have no idea where to begin and would appreciate all help I can get to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Can there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2=b^2\cdot p$, where $p$ is a prime number?

Comment: No. That can't be. Can we say the same thing about polynomials?

Comment: Well, what was your reasoning for why it's impossible to do with integers? Presumably you used somewhere the idea of unique prime factorization in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ - do you know whether the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ has this property?

Comment: My reasoning was this, if $a^2=b^2p$ then $a=b \sqrt p$ but $\sqrt p$ isn't an integer, and $b$ is an integer, so $b \sqrt p$ can't be an integer.

Comment: @OriaGruber: It isn't enough to know only that $\sqrt{p}$ isn't an integer; for example, $\frac{1}{2}$ is not an integer, but
$$3=6\cdot\frac{1}{2}.$$
What you need to know is that $\sqrt{p}$ is *irrational* (see Bill's answer, for example).

Comment: So in essence, I need to show that $(x^2+1)$ is prime and that should suffice to show that such an $f$ does not exist. Will eisenstein's criterion work here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion

Comment: @Oria: No, Eisenstein's criterion will not apply here because $1$ is not divisible by any prime number. But it is easy to see that $x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ because if it factored, it would of course have to factor into linear terms (since $x^2+1$ is only of degree $2$). But a polynomial $h\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ having a linear factor $(x-a)$ - that is, having $h=(x-a)\cdot k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ - is the same as having the number $a$ as a root. But the roots of $x^2+1$ are $\pm i$, which are not rational numbers.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ $ Most all proofs showing $\sqrt{p}$ irrational also work to show that $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is an irrational polynomial, i.e. not a quotient of polynomials, e.g. compare parity of exponents of the prime $\,p = x^2+1\,$ in $\, f^2 = pg^2\,$ using the *uniqueness* of prime factorizations. Or apply the [Rational Root Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242) to deduce any rational (function) root $\,Y\,$ of $\ Y^2 - (x^2+1)\, =\, 0\,$ must have denominator dividing $\,1,\,$  so $\,x^2+1 = Y^2\,$ is the square of a polynomial, contradiction. Or employ Bezout's gcd identity as in the proof below. Most proofs using unique prime factorization generalize to any ring with this property (a UFD or possibly also to gcd domains), and most proofs using Bezout's gcd identity generalize to any PID.

**Theorem** $\quad \rm r = \sqrt{f}\;\;$ is a polynomial, $ $ if a rational function, $ $ for polynomial $\:\rm f\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$

**Proof** $\ \ $ Let $\rm\,\ \color{#0a0}{r = \large{\frac{a}b}},\ a,b\in{\Bbb Q}[x],\,\ \gcd(a,b) = 1\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#C00}{ad\!-\!bc \,=\, \bf 1}\;$  for $\:\rm c,d \in \mathbb{Q}[x]\,\ $ by [Bezout,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity) since $\,\Bbb Q[x]\,$ has Division with smaller remainder, so has a Euclidean gcd algorithm.

$\rm\color{#C00}{That\,}$ and $\rm\: r^2\! = \color{#90f}{\bf f}\:\Rightarrow\ \color{#0a0}{0\, =\, (a\!-\!br)}\, (c\!+\!dr) \ =\ ac\!-\!bd\color{#90f}{\bf f} \:+\: \color{#c00}{\bf 1}\cdot r \ \Rightarrow\ r \in \mathbb{Q}[x]\ \ \ $ **QED**

The proof [easily generalizes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4585/242) to roots of *monic* quadratic polynomials (and [to higher degrees](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/91595/242)).

Comment: As always, a beautifully thought out and well linked response. ($+1$)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $P(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$ and $x^2+1|P^2(x)$ then $P(\pm i)=0$. Use this to deduce that $X^2+1 |P(X)$.