# If $(f(x))^n$ is a polynomial for all $n\ge 2$, $n\in\mathbb Z$, then is $f(x)$ a polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is such that $(f(x))^n$ is a polynomial for all $n\ge 2$, $n\in\mathbb Z$. Is $f(x)$ necessarily a polynomial?

My attempt: The condition is equivalent to $(f(x))^p$ being a polynomial for all primes $p$. Also, clearly $f(x)$ is a ratio of two polynomials.

Comment: HINT: Now that you know it is a ratio of two polynomials, try to prove the following simpler assertion and generalize: If a rational number is the $n$th root of an integer that rational number is also an integer.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM $\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^3=x\sqrt{x}$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM For your function cube is not a polynomial.

Comment: @PVanchinathan Thanks, it's clear now.

Comment: @PVanchinathan I've written an answer based on the comment.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ f^2,f^3\in \Bbb R[x]\,\Rightarrow\, f = f^3/f^2 \in \Bbb R(x)\,$ so $\,f^2 \in \Bbb R[x]\,\,\Rightarrow\,f \in \Bbb R[x]\, $ by the Rational Root Test (which works over any UFD, with [same proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242) as in $\,\Bbb Z)$

More explicitly if $\,f^2 = p\in \Bbb R[x]\,$ then $\,f\,$ is a root of the *monic* $\,y^2 - p\in S[y]$ over the UFD $\,S = \Bbb R[x],\,$ so by RRT the reduced denominator of $\,f\,$ divides the lead coef $= 1\,$ of $\ y^2 - p.\ $  Hence the denominator of $\,f\,$ is a unit, i.e. the polynomial fraction $\,f\,$ is "integral", i.e. $\,f\in \Bbb R[x].$

**Remark** $\ $ This is a polynomial analog of the classical irrationality proofs for square-roots of numbers. Most of the proofs for numbers will also work here (e.g. [comparing the parity of exponents](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/669926/242) in the (unique) prime factorizations on both sides).

Comment: $\mathbb R(x)$ denotes the set of functions that are ratios of two polynomials with real coefficients?

Comment: @user263326 Yes, rational "functions", i.e. polynomial fractions.

Comment: To (hopefully) clarify to readers: the polynomial to which the Rational Root Test is being applied is $T^2-f(x)^2$, in the ring $S[T]$ where $S=\Bbb R[x]$.

Comment: @GregMartin Correct.

Comment: In this answer you're assuming $f^2\not\equiv 0$, but it's trivial that if $f^2\equiv 0$, then $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: @user263326 Right. Typically hints don't explicitly address trivial cases.

Answer (score 2):

If $f=0$ you're done, so suppose otherwise.
Write:

$$f(x)=\frac{f^3(x)}{f^2(x)}=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)},$$

for polynomials $p,q$.

From which it follows that

$$q(x)=f^2(x)=\frac{p^2(x)}{q^2(x)}.$$

Now suppose that $p(x)$ has a root $r$ and $q(r)\neq 0$

Rearranging this gives $q^3(x)=p^2(x)$ locally around $r$. This is clearly impossible since $q,p$ are polynomials, hence $q(x)$ and $p(x)$ must have the same roots (repeat the argument for $q(x)$ having a root $r$ but $p(x)$ not). You can show that $p(x)$ must have degree larger than $q(x)$ from which it follows that $f(x)$ is a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. More generally:

> If $D$ is a UFD, $R$ a ring extension of $D$, $x\in R$ such that $x^n\in D$ for all $n>1$, then $x\in D$.

*Proof.* $(x^2)^2\mid(x^3)^2\overset{UFD}\implies x^2\mid x^3\implies x\in D$.

Yours is the case $D=\mathbb R[x]$, $R=\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question based on the comment.

If $(f(x))^2\equiv 0$, then $f(x)\equiv 0$ is also a polynomial. Let $(f(x))^2\not\equiv 0$.

$f(x)=\frac{(f(x))^3}{(f(x))^2}=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ is a ratio of two polynomials $p(x)$, $q(x)$  with real coefficients.

$f(x)^2=r(x)$ is another polynomial with real coefficients.

Therefore $(p(x))^2=(q(x))^2r(x)$, so $(q(x))^2$ divides $(p(x))^2$, i.e. $q(x)$ divides $p(x)$, so $f(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ is a polynomial.

It was enough to claim that $(f(x))^2$, $(f(x))^3$ are polynomials to conclude $f(x)$ is a polynomial. More generally, $(f(x))^m$, $(f(x))^{km+1}$ could be polynomials for some $k,m\in\mathbb Z^+$ to conclude $f(x)$ is also a polynomial.

As barto claims in a comment, by [Bézout's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) it's enough to know $(f(x))^a$, $(f(x))^b$ are polynomials, where $a,b\in\mathbb Z^+$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, to conclude that $f(x)$ is a polynomial.

Comment: By Bézout's theorem it even suffices that $f(x)^a$ and $f(x)^b$ are polynomials for some coprime $a,b$.

Comment: @barto Indeed.${}$