# Is square root of an integer, either an integer or an irrational number, but never (non-integer) rational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$\sqrt a$ is either an integer or an irrational number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/sqrt-a-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number)

$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational number, but $\sqrt{9} = 3$ is an integer.
Are there such integers whose square root is a (non-integer)rational number?

Comment: Well, integers are rational numbers. You presumably mean non-integer rational numbers.

Comment: Every integer is a rational number. I suppose you mean "Are there integers whose square root is rational, but not an integer?" In fact, the answer is no.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many prior questions, e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/4467/242 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/5/242 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/26499/242 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/22423/242 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/11872/242

Comment: @GeoffRobinson (you should) write it as an answer.

Comment: @tzador, please read the duplicate question. It says that the square root of every (positive) integer is either an integer or irrational. There is no integer whose square root is a rational fraction.

Comment: One way of looking at this is to try taking the square of a rational number $q$ which is not an integer. If this is in its lowest terms, then the denominator of $q$ will have a non-trivial prime factor $p$ and $q^2$ will have denominator divisible by $p^2$. I mention this because the ideas here, though seemingly trivial, have fruitful and interesting generalisations.

Comment: @Jennifer: It is a duplicate, so no real need.

Answer (score -5):

Assume $x^2 =\frac{m}{n}$ where $m \in \mathbb Z$ and $ n \in \mathbb N$

this implies $x = \frac{\sqrt{m}}{\sqrt{n}}$

which means that for an integer to have a rational root it's root must be the ratio of two integer roots. For this ratio to not be an integer m and n must be distinct which implies that x is not an integer quantity.

Comment: To be clear this means that there isn't an integer rational with a rational root that isn't an integer.

Comment: "For this ratio to not be an integer m and n must be distinct which implies that x is not an integer quantity." You need to prove this, as nothing you have said makes it obvious this is true. In fact I can't think of any proof of this sentence which doesn't prove the whole theorem along the way. Thus your answer is incomplete/wrong.