# Complex Roots of Unity and the GCD

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm looking for a proof of this statement. I just don't know how to approach it. I recognize that $z$ has $a$ and $b$ roots of unity, but I can't seem to figure out what that tells me.

If $z \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfies $z^a = 1$ and $z^b = 1$ then
$z^{gcd(a,b)} = 1$.

Comment: If $z^a = 1$ and $z^b = 1$, then also $z^{a+b} = 1$, or more generally $z^{ax+by} = 1$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was all the information given in the statement I seek to prove.

Comment: Do you know that if the gcd is $d$, there are integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=d$?  Then $z^d=z^{ax+by}$. Continue.

Comment: Is this logic sound? If $z^a = 1$, then $z^{ax} = 1$. Likewise if $z^b = 1$, then $z^{by} = 1$. Multiplying them together, we get $z^{ax+by} = 1$. By Bezout's we know $ax+by = gcd(a,b)$, so it must be true that $z^{gcd(a,b)} = 1$.

Comment: @DominickGerard: Yes, those are the steps you should write down; but there are a couple important points to improve the presentation of your proof.  You should explain what $x$ and $y$ are when you introduce them.  Notice that they have to be integers-- it wouldn't necessarily work with $x=\frac{1}{3}$, for example.  In particular, you want them to be integer solutions to $ax+by=\rm{gcd}(a,b)$.  This equation certainly isn't true for just any integers $x$ and $y$!  I recommend starting off with Bezout's theorem, so that the reader knows just what you mean by $x$ and $y$.

Comment: When you think you have knocked a proof into good shape, post it as an answer to your own question. If it holds up under our intense scrutiny, then you can accept it.

Comment: @Dominick Girard: Your last sentence didn't have enough detail. Note that $z^d=z^{ax+by}=z^{ax}z^{by}$. But $z^{ax}=(z^a)^x$, and therefore $\dots$.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: I deleted and rewrote, because of a typo (Dubugue!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** $\:$ The set of $\rm\:n\in \mathbb Z$ such that $\rm\:z^n = 1\:$ is closed under *subtraction* [so it is closed under $\rm\:gcd$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4715/242)

Recall gcds may be computed by repeated *subtraction* (anthyphairesis, Euclidean algorithm)

Comment: Very nice short conceptual solution.