# Gcd number theory proof: $(a^n-1,a^m-1)= a^{(m,n)}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that if $a>1$ then $(a^n-1,a^m-1)= a^{(m,n)}-1$

where $(a,b) = \gcd(a,b)$

I've seen one proof using the Euclidean algorithm, but I didn't fully understand it because it wasn't very well written.
I was thinking something along the lines of have $d= a^{(m,n)} - 1$ and then showing 
$d|a^m-1$ and $d|a^n-1$ and then if $c|a^m-1$ and $c|a^n-1$, then $c\le d$.

I don't really know how to show this though...

I can't seem to be able to get $d* \mathbb{K} = a^m-1$.

Any help would be beautiful!

Comment: You've probably seen factorizations (of polynomials) like $x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)$ (and so e.g. $x^{10}-1=(x^5-1)(x^5+1)$) and $x^3-1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ (and so e.g. $x^{12} = (x^4-1)(x^8+x^4+1)$). Do you know the generalization to $x^{jk}-1 = (x^j-1)($something$)$?

Answer (score 4):

We want to prove $\forall n, m :P(n,m)$, where $P(n,m)$ is defined as $(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{(n,m)} - 1$.

This proof uses a kind of strong induction on $(n,m)$.  In other words, it is assumed, outside of base cases, that if $a < n$ and $b < m$, we can assume $P(a,m)$ and $P(n,b)$ in a proof of $P(n,m)$..

Since gcd is symmetric, $P(n,m) \Leftrightarrow P(m,n)$

Base case 1, $m = n$. $(a^m-1, a^n-1) =  a^n - 1 = a^{(n,n)} - 1 = a^{(m,n)} - 1$

Base case 2, $m = 0$.  $(a^n - 1, a^0 - 1) = (a^n - 1, 0) = a^n - 1 = a^{(n,0)} - 1$.

Base case 3, $n = 0$.  same as case 2 by symmetry.

Case 4, $0 < n < m$.  Since $y > x \Rightarrow (x,y) = (x, y-x)$, $(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = (a^n - 1, a^m - a^n) = \left(a^n - 1, a^n(a^{m-n} - 1\right))$   Since $a^n$ and $a^n - 1$ have no factors in common, $(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = (a^n - 1, a^{m-n} - 1)$.

From induction, $(a^n - 1, a^{m-n} - 1) = a^{(n,m-n)} - 1 = a^{(n,m)} - 1$.  So $(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{(n,m)} - 1$

Case 5, 0 < m < n:  Use symmetry and case 4.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ By below $\rm\,\ a^M\!-\!1,\:a^N\!-\!1\ $ and $\rm\,\ a^{\,(M,N)}\!-\!1\ $  have the same set $\rm\,S\,$ of common divisors $\rm\,d,\, $ therefore they have the same *greatest* common divisor $\rm\ (= \max\ S).$

$$\begin{eqnarray}\rm\ \ mod\,\ d\!:\ \ a^M,\:a^N\equiv 1&\iff&\rm ord(a)\ |\ M,N\color{#c00}\iff ord(a)\ |\ (M,N)\iff a^{\,(M,N)}\equiv 1\\
\rm i.e.\ \ \ d\ |\ a^M\!-\!1,\:a^N\!-\!1\ &\iff&\rm\ d\ |\ a^{\,(M,N)}\!-\!1,\qquad\ \ \, where \rm\quad\! (M,N)\, :=\, gcd(M,N)
\end{eqnarray}$$

**Note** $\,\ $ Above we used  $\ a\mid b,c \color{#c00}\iff a\mid (b,c),\ $ the fundamental [universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242) of the gcd. Compare $\, a<b,c \!\iff\! a< \min(b,c),\ $ and $\  a\subset b,c\iff a\subset b\cap c.\,$ Exploiting such "iff" definitions allows us to easily simultaneously prove *both* directions of the eqivalence.

The conceptual structure that lies at the heart of this simple proof is the ubiquitous **order ideal.** $\ $ See my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/if-the-order-divides-a-prime-p-then-the-order-is-p-or-1/4715#4715) for more on this and the more familiar additive form of a **denominator ideal.**

More generally $\rm\ gcd(f(m), f(n)) = f(gcd(m,n))\ \ \, if\, \ \ f(n) \equiv f(n\!-\!m)\,\ \ (mod\ f(m)),\, $ and $\rm\, f(0) = 0.\, $ See my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/number-theory-proving-question/7561#7561) for a simple inductive proof.

In fact there is a q-analog: the result also holds true for polynomials $\rm \ f(n) = (x^n\!-\!1)/(x\!-\!1),\, $ and $\rm\ x\to 1\ $ yields the integer case (Bezout identity) - see my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/number-theory-proving-question/7479#7479) for a simple proof.