# A proof using Fermat's Little Theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be prime and let $a\in Z$ such that p $\nmid$ a. Prove that if $k$ is the smallest integer such that $a^k\equiv 1 \pmod p$, then $k|(p-1)$.

I feel like i have to use the division algorithm. And also that the easiest way to approach this would be by way of contradiction. Any ideas?

Comment: `p \nmid a` $p \nmid a$ (you should also use `\mid` for "divides": $k \mid (p+1)$).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ With only slightly more effort one can view this as a special case of a *basic* result.

The set $\,\cal O\,$ of integers $\rm\:n >0\:$ such that $\rm\:a^n \equiv 1\:$ is *closed under positive subtraction,* i.e.

$$\rm \color{#0A0}n>\color{#C00}m\,\in\,{\cal O}\ \Rightarrow\ 1\equiv \color{#0A0}{a^n} \equiv a^{n-m}\, \color{#C00}{a^m} \equiv a^{n-m}\, \Rightarrow\ n\!-\!m\,\in\,{\cal O}$$

Thus, by theorem below, every element of $\rm\,\cal O\,$ is divisible by its least element $\rm\:\ell\ \! $ := order of $\rm\,a.$

**Theorem** $\ \ $ If a nonempty set of positive integers $\rm\,\cal O\,$ satisfies $\rm\ n > m\, \in\, {\cal O} \ \Rightarrow\  n\!-\!m\, \in\, \cal O$
then every element of $\rm\,\cal O\,$ is a multiple of the least element $\rm\:\ell \in\cal O.$

**Proof** $\  $ If not there's a least nonmultiple $\rm\:n\in \cal O,\:$ contra  $\rm\:n\!-\!\ell \in \cal O\:$ is a nonmultiple of $\rm\:\ell. \, $ **QED**

For more on the key innate structure  see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4715/242) on *order ideals* and *denominator ideals.*

Answer (score 0):

you know that
$$
a^{p-1}=1\mod p
$$
Write p-1 = kq + r, then

$$
1 = a^{p-1}=  a^{kq} a ^r = a^r
\mod p
$$and as $r<k$, $r=0$.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a group theoretical proof. The group of invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ has order $p-1$. By Lagrange's theorem, the order of each element is a divisor of the group order.

Indeed, let $G$ be a finite group; if $g\in G$, the least positive integer $k$ such that $g^k=1$ equals the cardinality of $\langle g\rangle=\{g^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, which is a subgroup of $G$.