# Prove $\gcd(k, l) = d \Rightarrow \gcd(2^k - 1, 2^l - 1) = 2^d - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

This is a problem for a graduate level discrete math class that I'm hoping to take next year (as a senior undergrad). The problem is as stated in the title:

> Given that $\gcd(k, l) = d$, prove that $\gcd(2^k - 1, 2^l - 1) = 2^d
>  - 1$.

The problem also says "hint: use Euclid's lemma," although I'm not sure what part of the problem should be applied to. I've been thinking about it for a few days and I'm completely stumped.

I'm not really even sure how to show that it divides either $2^k - 1$ or $2^l - 1$. From the given, we know that $\exists c: dc = k$. We need to show that $\exists c': (2^d - 1)c' = 2^k - 1$. Obviously $c' = 2^c$ gives you $(2^d - 1)c' = 2^k - 2^c$, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the extra terms that the $- 1$ brings in in various places.

From Euclid's lemma on the left side, you know $\exists i: di = k - l$, and applying it on the right side, you know it suffices to show that $\gcd(2^k - 2^l, 2^l - 1) = 2^d - 1$. And by Bezout's identity, it's enough to show that $2^d - 1$ can be written as a linear combination of either of those things.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ By below $\rm\,\ a^M\!-\!1,\:a^N\!-\!1\ $ and $\rm\,\ a^{\,(M,N)}\!-\!1\ $  have the same set $\rm\,S\,$ of *common* divisors $\rm\,d,\, $ therefore they have the same *greatest* common divisor $\rm\ (= \max\ S).$

$$\begin{eqnarray}\rm\ \ mod\,\ d\!:\ \ a^M,\:a^N\equiv 1&\iff&\rm ord(a)\ |\ M,N\color{#c00}\iff ord(a)\ |\ (M,N)\iff a^{\,(M,N)}\equiv 1\\
\rm i.e.\ \ \ d\ |\ a^M\!-\!1,\:a^N\!-\!1\ &\iff&\rm\ d\ |\ a^{\,(M,N)}\!-\!1,\qquad\ \ \, where \rm\quad\! (M,N)\, :=\, gcd(M,N)
\end{eqnarray}$$

**Remark** $\ $ Above we used  $\ a\mid b,c \color{#c00}\iff a\mid (b,c),\ $ the fundamental [universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242) of the gcd. Compare $\, a<b,c \!\iff\! a< \min(b,c),\ $ and $\  a\subset b,c\iff a\subset b\cap c.\,$ Exploiting such universal "iff" definitions allows us to quickly and easily simultaneously prove *both* directions of the equivalence.

The conceptual structure that lies at the heart of this simple proof is the ubiquitous **order ideal.** $\ $ See my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/if-the-order-divides-a-prime-p-then-the-order-is-p-or-1/4715#4715) for more on this and the more familiar additive form of a **denominator ideal.**

More generally: $\rm\ gcd(f(m), f(n))\, =\, f(gcd(m,n))\ \ \, if\, \ \ f(n) \equiv f(n\!-\!m)\,\ \ (mod\ f(m)),\, $ and $\rm\, f(0) = 0.\, $ See my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/number-theory-proving-question/7561#7561) for a simple inductive proof.

In fact there is a q-analog: the result also holds true for polynomials $\rm \ f(n) = (x^n\!-\!1)/(x\!-\!1),\, $ and $\rm\ x\to 1\ $ yields the integer case (Bezout identity) - see my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/number-theory-proving-question/7479#7479) for a simple proof.

Comment: Ah, I guess this is a dupe then, thanks for the proof and the point in the correct direction.