# What is $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: group-theory

Can I define the quotient group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ under addition as $\{\frac{a}{b}|a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ or is that wrong? How would you define it?

Comment: I meant the quotient group under addition

Comment: So you didn't mean all rational numbers except for integers?

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: Can you please describe this set in plain English?

Comment: @barakmanos the quotient group of the rational numbers (with addition as operation) by the subgroup of integers. See the defintion of [Quotient Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group) if necessary.

Comment: What you have written is wrong. The set of elements of ${\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}$ is equal to the set of cosets $\{\frac{a}{b} + {\mathbb Z} \mid a,b \in {\mathbb Z}, b \ne 0 \}$.

Comment: $p/q$ ~ $p/q + z, \forall z \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: It is the [rational circle group.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1128611/242)

Answer (score 1):

The set under consideration is as you say the quotient group of the rationals with addition by the integers.

Taken strictly its elements are equivalence classes of rational numbers, 
so 
$$\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} = \{[q] \colon q \in \mathbb{Q} \}$$ where $[q] = \{q' \in \mathbb{Q} \colon q - q' \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Having said this what you mean is perhaps a set of representative of the classes, here you could take all rationals $q$ such that $0 \le q <1$, or staying with your notation all $a/b$ with a nonzero natural number $b$ and $0 \le a < b$ also natural (and $\gcd(a,b)=1$ if you want to eliminate duplicates).

However if you do this you need to be carful how you define your operation: 
you could say for $0 \le q,q' < 1$ you have $q\oplus q' = q + q'$ if $q+q'<1$ and $q\oplus q' = q + q' - 1$ if $1\le q+q'$ (note that $q + q'$ is always less than $2$); here I denote by $\oplus$ the operation on your set of representatives and by $+$ the usual addition in the rationals.

Answer (score 0):

The correct definition of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is given by taking $\mathbb{Q}$ and identifying elements $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ whenever $a-b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

You can make the identification
$$\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} = \{e^{2i\pi t}\in\mathbb{C}|t\in\mathbb{Q}\}\subset S^1$$
the "rational points" in the (complex) unit circle.