# Show $\,p\mid 9^q -1 \implies q\mid p-1$ for odd primes $p$ and $q$

Tags: number-theory

If $p$ and $q$ are odd primes show that $$p|(9^q -1) \implies q|(p-1).$$ ....

I am having difficulty to prove this.

Yes that was the question I have misunderstood between 9 and q!!!

Comment: why?? i cannot understand

Comment: What you have is a factorization of $q^6-1$... Also, see my solution.

Comment: sorry for that!!! i have gone mad!!!

Comment: $19\mid 5^9-1$, but $5\nmid 19-1$. Also $19\nmid 5-1$.

Comment: @tone note that Jykri's example shows you that $ p \not \mid q-1$ too.

Comment: thanks for the counter examples

Comment: Probably it should be $\ p\mid 9^q-1\,\Rightarrow\, q\mid p-1\  $

Comment: @tone what exactly is the correct question? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $ $ Apply twice: $\ 9^{\:\!\large n}\!\equiv 1\!\iff\! \color{#0a0}{{\rm ord}\,9}\mid n,\,$ by the [Order Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242), i.e.

$\!\!\bmod p\!:\ 9^{\:\!\large q}\equiv 1,\,$ so $\,9\,$ has $\rm\color{#0a0}{order}$ dividing $ $ *prime* $\,q,\,$ so it must be $\,\color{#0a0}q\,$ (not $\color{#c00}{\bf 1}$ else *odd* $\,p\mid 9^{\large \color{#c00}{\bf 1}}\!-1),\,$ thus by little Fermat $\,9^{\:\!\large p-1}\!\equiv 1,\,$ so $\,\color{#0a0}{q}\mid p\!-\!1.\ $ [note $\,p\mid 9^{\:\!\large q}\!-1\,\Rightarrow\,p\nmid 9,\,$ so Fermat applies].

**Remark** $ $ The same proof works if we replace $\,9\,$ by any integer $\,a\,$  and we add the hypothesis $\,p\nmid a^{\color{#c00}{\bf 1}}\!-1\,$ (to ensure $a$ has order $\,\rm\color{#0a0}{q}\,$ (vs. $\color{#c00}{\bf 1})$ modulo $\,p)$.

Comment: More generally see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4715/242).