# Proof about the length of the period $a\pmod m$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Theorem 4-3 if $a^u \equiv 1\pmod m$, then $ord_m\text{ } a|u$.

Proof: Put $ord_m\text{ }a=t$, and let $u=qt+r$, $0 \leq r\ <t$. Then

$$a^u =a^{qt+r}=((a^t)^q)*a^r \equiv a^r \equiv 1(mod\text{ } m)$$

and if r were different from zero, there would be a contradiction with the definition of t.

How does that show $ord_m a|u$?

Comment: If $r=0,$ then $u=qt$ is divisible by $t=ord_m a.$

Comment: why there would be a contradiction with the definition of t?

Comment: Because $t$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $a^n\equiv 1\pmod m.$ But one is led to $a^r\equiv1\pmod m$ with $r\lt t.$

Comment: how do we deduce $a^r \equiv 1(mod\text{ } m)$?

Comment: You deduced it in the third line, didn't you?

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1200149/242) and [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1158979/242) for more conceptual viewpoints.

Comment: I can't understand why $(a^t)^q*a^r \equiv a^r\equiv 1(mod\text{ } m)$

Comment: I got it, because $(a,m)=1$, so $(a^{tq},m)=1$ which implies that $a^{tq}$ has a multiplicative inverse right?