# Lagrange's theorem question - have I got it correct?

Tags: group-theory

{${G,*}$} is a group of order 15 with identity element ${e}$.
There is an element ${a\in G}$ such that ${a^3\neq e}$ and ${a^5\neq e}$.
Prove that {${G,*}$} is a cyclic group with generator ${a}$.

This is what I have written:
By Lagrange's theorem subgroups can only exist of order 1,3,5 or 15.
Since ${a\neq e}$, ${a^3\neq e}$ and ${a^5\neq e}$ then ${a^{15}=e}$.
Therefore the order of ${a}$ is the same as the order of ${G}$.
Therefore ${G=<a>}$, and hence G is cyclic.

Is this correct?  Have I missed anything?

Comment: Pretty good I would say :) Indeed since the period of $a$ is $15$ it will necessarily generate all members of the group when "iterated". Otherwise it would have had a smaller period which is false.

Comment: The logic employed is a special case of the frequently useful [Order Test.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1872217/242)

Answer (score 1):

It is perfect.

Perhaps you skipped a few steps, like the fact that the order of $a$ is the order of the subgroup $\langle a \rangle$, which must be $1,3,5$ or $15$ by lagrange's theorem.

And then noticing that if the order is $1$ or $3$ then $a^3=e$ and if the order is $5$ then $a^5=e$. So you finally conclude the order is $15$.