# $n$ divides $\phi(a^n -1)$ where $a, n$ are positive integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, totient-function

> Let $n$ and $a$ be positive integers with $a > 1$. I need to show that $n$ divides $\phi(a^n -1)$.

Here, $\phi$ denotes the [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Could any one give me a hint?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421151/prove-n-mid-phi2n-1 for the particular case when $a = 2$.

Comment: Special case $m = \phi(a^n-1)$  of the [Order Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242), i.e. $\,n={\rm ord}_m a\mid \phi(m)\ \ $

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A group theoretic solution can be given, (though this solution requires some advanced concepts yet it is very elegant and beautiful).

Let $m= a^n-1$.

Consider the group $G = (\mathbb{Z} / m\mathbb{Z})^*$ or rather $(\mathbb{Z}_m)^*$.

This group has $\phi(m)$ elements or rather the order of the group is $\phi(m)$.

Let $\bar a \in \mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z}$ be the remainder class of the integer $a$ modulo $m$. Then, $\bar a \in G$, as $\gcd(a,m) = \gcd(a,a^n-1)=1$.

Consider the subgroup $H=\left<\bar a\right>$ that is the subgroup generated by $\bar a$.

Now $a^n\equiv 1 \mod m$ (where $m=a^n-1$ and $n$ is the smallest integer with this property), but no positive integer $i<n$ satisfies $a^i \equiv 1 \mod m$ (since $a^i - 1$ is a positive integer smaller than $m$). This implies that order of $H$ equals $n$.

Now as the order of a subgroup always divides the order of a group we have $n\mid\phi(a^n-1)$ .

Answer (score 9):

Hint:

$$a^n\equiv 1\pmod {a^n-1}$$
and $$a^d\not\equiv 1\pmod {a^n-1}$$
if $0<d<n$ (why?).

Answer (score 8):

Hint for proving that $n \mid \phi(a^n - 1)$ for all integers $n > 0$ and $a > 1$:

1. Find the smallest positive integer $i$ with the property that
   $$ a^i\equiv1\pmod{a^n-1}.$$
2. Now you know the order of the coset $\overline{a}$ in the group $G=\mathbb{Z}_{a^n-1}^*$. Apply Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Dear Jyrki! Nice and simple group-theoretic proof! +1

Answer (score 8):

You can apply Euler's Theorem like this:
$${a}^{\phi\left(m^n-1\right)}\equiv 1 \pmod{m^n-1}$$
Also, you can use this fact:
$$\left(x^a-1,x^b-1\right)=x^{\left(a,b\right)}-1$$

Comment: Hello Issac Yiu! Welcome to MSE!

Comment: ...lol,hahahaha

Answer (score 2):

$a$ has multiplicative order $n$ in the ring of integers modulo $a^n - 1$, but this order must divide the order of the group of units modulo $a^n - 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Claim 1:
$\text{ord}_{a^{n}-1}(a) = n$

Proof:

Let $x = \text{ord}_{a^{n}-1}(a)$. Then $a^x-1 \equiv 0 \pmod {a^{n}-1}$. If  $0 < x < n$, then $a^{x} < a^n$ so we are done.

Claim 2: $n| \phi(a^{n}-1)$.

Proof:

We know that $a^{ \phi(a^{n}-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod { a^{n}-1}$ since $\gcd(a, a^{n}-1) = 1$. Now since the order of $a$ is $n$, it immediately follows that $n| \phi(a^{n}-1)$.