# Show that $n$ divides $\phi(a^n -1)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Show that $n$ divides $\phi(a^n -1)$ for any $a>n$ where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.

I would really appreciate a hint.

Comment: Hint: What is the order of $a$ modulo $a^n-1$?

Comment: Hint:Use Lagrange's theorem on groups.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930235/number-theoretic-proof-that-n-mid-phian-1?noredirect=1&lq=1 or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398165/n-divides-phian-1-where-a-n-are-positive-integer