# Given a number, $N = 55^5 + 17^5 – 72^5$, then how can we prove that the number is divisible both $3$ and $17$ in a simple way?

Tags: contest-math, divisibility

I came across this question as a MCQ among which the correct option was that this number is divisible by both $3$ and $17$.

Now one way to show that this number is indeed divisible by both  $3$ and $17$ by using the principle of cyclicity of remainders for both the numbers i.e. $3$ and $17$ but that is very time consuming and also cumbersome for such big numbers. So I was wondering if there could be any smart and easy to way to show that this number is divisible by aforementioned numbers.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Recall $a\pm b$ is a factor of $a^5\pm b^5$ and note that $17=72-55$ and $55+17=3\times 24$.

Comment: It is easier to write that in a comment than as an answer? @user10354138

Comment: @user10354138 : Thanks for making me recall this property. It simplified the proof.

Comment: I'm confused why the first answer is so elaborate when this problem is an elementary application of modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this as a HINT:

I am not aware of how to solve a degree $5$ expression that you have written, but I hope the below helps and gives you a hint. I have done it for a degree $3$ equation, I suppose this method satisfies for all odd powers, but I couldn't prove it (I'm a junior student myself). Hope this helps:

Note that: $55+17-72=0$

Let's consider $x=55$, $y=17$, $z=-72$

Therefore, we get $x+y+z=0$

$$x^3+y^3+z^3 - 3xyz= (x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2 - xy-yz-zx)$$
$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz = S_1(\sum x^2 -S_2)$$
$$x^3+y^3+z^3 = 3xyz$$

[Because $S_1=x+y+z=0$]

So the expression simplifies to:

$$55^3+17^3-72^3 = 3 \cdot 55 \cdot 17 \cdot (-72)$$

(I have considered $3$ degree, like I said above)

So then you can find factors, visibly $3$ and $17$ are factors.

Comment: For larger powers that will be impractical, but using modular arithmetic still works simply (e.g. see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

> using the principle of cyclicity of remainders for both the numbers i.e. $3$ and $17$ but that is very time consuming and also cumbersome

No, in fact in general it is likely the *quickest* and *easiest* method, viz.

$\quad{\rm suppose}\ \ \, N\, = 55^n + 17^n - 72^n_{\phantom{|^|}}\,$ for $\,{\rm\color{#90f}{odd}}\,\ n\ge 1$
$\quad\!\!\bmod 17\!:\ N\,\equiv\, \color{#c00}{4^n}\, +\ 0^n\, -\ \color{#c00}{4^n}\equiv\, 0_{\phantom{|^|}}$
$\quad\!\!\bmod 3\!:\ \ \  N\,\equiv\  1^n +\ \color{orange}2^n \ -\ 0^n \equiv\, 0\ $ [via](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) $\, \color{orange}2^{n}\equiv (\color{orange}{-1})^n\equiv -1\,$ by $\,n\,\ \rm\color{#90f}{odd}$

**Remark** $ $ More generally we can exploit the innate modular $\:\!\rm\color{#c00}{symmetry}$ as follows

[Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/787204/242) $\ $ If $\,\ m\mid \color{#c00}{a\!-\!c},\,\ \overline m \mid a\!-\!d\ $ and  $\ m,\overline m,b\,$ are pairwise-coprime then

$\qquad\qquad\quad  m\overline m\mid  a^n\!+b^n\!-c^n\!-d^n\!\iff {\rm lcm}(o_m(d/b),o_{\overline m}(c/b))\mid n$

where $\,o_n(x) :=$ order of $\,x\pmod{\! n}.\,$ [For example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/787204/242)

$$17\cdot 19\,\mid  20^n+16^n-3^n-1^n \iff {\rm lcm}(\color{c00}2,\color{0a0}2)=2\mid n\qquad$$

See also [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/843751/242) that $\ 1897\mid 2903^n - 803^n - 464^n + 261^n$.

Using the above Theorem we can easily handle most all "contest" problems enjoying this symmetry. For *many* worked examples, follow the links (and their links ...).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use congruences and *lil' Fermat*:

- Mod $3$, $55\equiv 1$, $17\equiv 2$ and $72\equiv 0$, and $2$ has order $2$.
- Mod $17$, $55$ and $72\equiv 4$.

Comment: I think this is more of a comment. True, the common practices are fuzzy, and have evolved over time.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: For me it's a hint, to help beginners have the point of view that saves unnecessary computations. So I try to point that  congruences are here a powerful tool for that. Not I didn't solve completely the problems.

Comment: I agree with @Jyrki  For *many* ENT questions "use congruences and lil' Fermat" may well prove fruitful, but that doesn't mean it is a *good* answer (same for a hint: "use FTA = existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations"). The hurdles for many students often involve seeing *how* to (properly) apply these basic results. We should strive for *higher quality* content in *answers* (esp. those posted by highly experienced users - who should be role models).

Comment: @BillDubuque: When I poste hints, it's to give the O.P.s something to think about, and hopefully, improve their reflexes in the domain of the question. For me, the main difficulty is how to say enough for this aim, but nevertheless not almost give a full solution.