# GCD of powers minus 1

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

So I'm working on a proof that for positive integers $a$, $b$ and $c$, $c>1$, that $GCD(c^a-1,c^b-1)=c^{GCD(a,b)}-1$. Not sure what I should think about doing first.  My guess is I should start by showing the right hand side divides the numbers of the left. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, that would show that the LHS $\gcd$ is at least that big.

Answer (score 1):

$\!\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\quad \rm mod\,\ d\!:\ \ c^A,\:c^B\equiv 1&\iff&\rm ord(c)\ |\ A,B\color{}\iff ord(c)\ |\ (A,B)\iff c^{\,(A,B)}\equiv 1\\
\rm i.e.\ \ \ d\ |\ c^A\!-\!1,\:c^B\!-\!1\ &\iff&\rm d\ |\ c^{\,(A,B)}\!-\!1,\qquad\ \  where \rm\quad\! (A,B)\, :=\, gcd(A,B)
\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: How do you show the first step? The divisibility of A by ord(c)?

Comment: @time It's a basic result in group/number theory that $\ c^n=1\iff {\rm ord}(c)\mid n,\,$ e.g. [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) $\ \ $