# Find two natural numbers $m$ and $n$ such that the order of $n$ modulu $m$ equal to $2012$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find two natural numbers $m$ and $n$ such that $\gamma_m(n)=2012$

**My atempt:**

$$\varphi(n)\mid2012$$

$$\Longrightarrow \varphi(n)\in\{1,2,4,503,1006,2012\}$$

I am stuck here

Comment: But http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127109/order-of-an-element-modulo-n-divides-phin

Comment: The order divides the totient not the other way around. Also, $\phi(n)$ has no effect on $\gamma_m(n)$. You meant $\phi(m).$

Comment: What about $n=2$ and $m=2^{2012}-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolframalpha says there are no $m$ such that $\phi(m)=2012$ or $\phi(m)=4024$. So, it is natural to try $m=6037$, which is prime and has totient equal to $6035=3\cdot 2012$

$5$ is a primitive root in module $6037$. Thus, $5^3=625$ has order equal to $2012$.