# T o prove that if $n=2k$ and $1\leq i < n $ then $x^{2i}=e$ iff $i=k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $x$ be element of finite order $n$ in G.

To prove that if $n=2k$ and $1\leq i < n $ then $x^{2i}=e$ iff $i=k$

Now converse part i trivial. Now to prove that if $n=2k$ and assuming $x^{2i}=e$ i have to prove that $i=k$, Assuming contradiction that $i \neq k$ and so $i<k$ and thus $2i<2k$. This contradicts fact thatx has order $2k$.

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: It's correct, albeit it's not really a proof by contradiction. Sort of contrapositive rather (argument of type ‘otherwise…’).

Comment: that's correct but to be more pedanic, you should show the i>k case.

Comment: @ZackNi But i is not greater than k

Comment: @gathdi sorry I can only see i is less than or equals to n

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,x\,$ has order $\,2k\,$ [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) $\,x^{2i}=1\iff 2k\mid 2i\iff k\mid i$

Comment: is the op's proof correct?

Comment: @Zack Has already been adfressed in comments, but can also be inferred by the Hint (esp. if you follow the link, which leads to a conceptual explanation of the essence of the matter).