# A Hypothesis about Euler's Totient Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

Euler's totient theorem states that if $a$ and $n$ are coprime positive integers, then:
$$a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1\;(\mathrm{mod}\;n)$$
So if $k$ is a given positive integer, which satisfies:
$$\begin{cases}
a^k \equiv 1\;(\mathrm{mod}\;n)\\
k\leqslant \varphi(n)
\end{cases}$$

Does it necessarily hold that $k\,|\,\varphi(n)$?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/csgnotes/lambda.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwikkLS5k8DjAhVdi3AKHbLZBoYQFjACegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw3xIQ-odwUnzj4-5VdUd8hY&cshid=1563510825791

Comment: A comment about your title.

Answer (score 9):

No.  For example $n=16$, $\phi(n)=8$, $a=9$, $k=6$.  You can confirm that
$$9^6\equiv1\pmod{16}\quad\hbox{but}\quad 6\not\mid8\ .$$

However if $a$ is given and $k$ is the **smallest** positive integer such that $a^k\equiv1\pmod n$, then it is true that $k\mid\phi(n)$.  In the above example the smallest possible value of $k$ would have been $2$, not $6$.

Comment: Thank you! Then how can I prove it if $k$ is the smallest one?

Comment: Hint: divide $\phi(n)$ by $k$ to give quotient $q$ and remainder $r$.  Prove that $r$ is zero.

Comment: @XYZ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) for a conceptual proof.

Answer (score 3):

No...
This doesn't hold true if you take $n=16$ and $a=9$.  You may easily check that
$$9^6\equiv1\pmod{16}\quad\hbox{but}\quad 6\not\mid8\ .$$

Indeed, your assertion holds good if you are taking $k$ to be the order of $a$ in mod $n$. To find the minimum value of $k$, you should use an even stronger result which is Carmichael's Theorem; it states that the minimum value of $k$ is $\lambda(n)$ if $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

[image] 
**Note:** Value of Carmichael Function does not depends on $a$ and obviously $\lambda(n)\mid \phi(n)$ .

Comment: Why do you think Carmichael lambda is relevant here? Rather, it seems what the OP seeks is the *order* of $a,\ $ which generally is not the same as $\lambda(n).\ $

Answer (score 2):

No.

Say $n=15$.  Then $\varphi (15)=8$.  And $(4,15)=1$.  But $4^{6}=(4^2)^3\cong1\pmod{15}$.  And $6\not\mid8$.

Write $\varphi (n)=kq+r\,,r\lt k$.  Then $1\cong a^{\varphi (n)}\cong a^r$.  So if $k$ is the least such, then yes.