# Show that, for each $n \geq 2$, the whole number $4n^{2}-1$ is a Fermat pseudoprime to base $2n$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, pseudoprimes

I need to show that, for each $n \geq 2$, the whole number $4n^{2}-1$ is a Fermat pseudoprime to base $2n$; (hint: $4n^{2}-2$ is a multiple of $2$).

Fermat pseudoprime to base $2n$ means that $(2n)^{4n^{2}-2} \equiv 1 \mod 4n^{2}-1$, but from this point on I don't know what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you know what Fermat pseudoprime to base $2\color{maroon}n$ means?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, you are right, I edited.

Answer (score 3):

**Another hint besides the one given:**

$$(2n)^2\equiv 1\bmod 4n^2-1$$

Comment: And from that we can derive that $(2n)^{4n^{2}−2} \equiv 1 \mod 4n^{2}−1$, since we can rewrite it as $((2n)^{2}) ^ {(2n^{2}-1)}$. Right?

Comment: Yes, @DrMontorsi, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is a Fermat psp base $m\iff\bmod m\!:\ a^{m-1}\equiv 1\iff {\rm ord}(a)\mid m\!-\!1,\,$ by the [Order Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242)

Thus in OP we need:  $\ {\rm ord}(2n)\mid 4n^{\large 2}-2 = \color{#c00}2(2n^{\large 2}-1)\,$ with an obvious $\rm\color{#c00}{small\ factor}$ to try first.

It works: $\!\bmod 4n^{\large 2}\!-1\!:\,\ 4n^{\large 2}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, (2n)^{\large\color{#c00}2}\equiv\ \ldots $

Comment: This yields a *conceptual* way to discover it. Another conceptual way is to note that $\,4n^2-1 = (2n-1)(2n+1)$ and mod each factor $2n\equiv \pm1$  so has order at most $\color{#c00}2,\,$ so ditto mod their product, by CRT