# Show that: $p_{n+1}\nmid2^{p_1p_2...p_n}+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic

Let $p_1>p_2>...>p_{n+1}>3$ prime numbers. Show that: $$p_{n+1}\nmid2^{p_1p_2...p_n}+1$$

I tried to prove it by contradiction using Fermat's Theorem but i'm struggling.

Comment: What do you know about the order of $2$ modulo $p_{n+1}$?

Comment: Do you mean $3<p_1<p_2<\dots< p_{n+1}$ ?

Comment: @DanielFischer it divides $p_{n+1}-1$

Comment: @snowAuoue i dont think so

Comment: That's a good start. So if we had $p_{n+1} \mid 2^{p_1 p_2 \ldots p_n} + 1$, what else could you deduce about the order?

Comment: @DanielFischer it divides $2p_1p_2...p_n$ ??

Comment: Correct. And hence it divides … what?

Comment: @DanielFischer so i should say that the order is equal to $2$ because it divides the gcd of the two numbers which is impossible, isn't it ?

Comment: @DanielFischer or 1 and it is impossible too

Comment: Right. It divides the gcd of the two, which is $2$. So the order is either $1$ or $2$, but $2^1-1 = 1$ has no prime factor at all, and $2^2-1 = 3$, however $p_{n+1} > 3$ was assumed.

Comment: @DanielFischer just a question please. It is not obligatory to have $p_1>p_2>..>p_n+1$. They just need to be different and greater and $3$. No ?

Comment: You need a condition that ensures $p_k \nmid (p_{n+1} - 1)$ for $1 \leqslant k \leqslant n$. If the condition had been stated in that form, the solution would have been obvious, wouldn't it? So a condition was given that implies the above, but isn't obvious.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you for the help

Comment: I added an answer which gives a generalization like that you asked about.

Answer (score 2):

assume that $p_{n+1}\mid 2^{p_1 p_2\dots p_n}+1\Rightarrow p_{n+1}\mid 2^{2p_1 p_2\dots p_n}-1$, but $p_{n+1}\mid 2^{p_{n+1}-1}-1$, so

$$p_{n+1}\mid\gcd(2^{2p_1 p_2\dots p_n}-1,  2^{p_{n+1}-1}-1)=2^{\gcd(2p_1 p_2\dots p_n, p_{n+1}-1)}-1$$. since $p_{n+1}$ is smallest between these primes, $p_{n+1}-1$ can't have any common factors with $p_1,p_2,\dots p_n$. so $$\gcd(2p_1 p_2\dots p_n, p_{n+1}-1)=2$$
so $p_{n+1}\mid 2^2-1=3$ which is impossible. So we get a contradiction.

Comment: You are missing a -1 from $p_{n+1}|2^{p_{n+1}-1}-1$.

Comment: @N.S. Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @N.S. No, $p_{n+1}-1 < p_k$ for any $1\leq k \leq n$, so it can't be divisible by $p_k$.

Comment: Tip: when you repeat a proof given in comments it is customary to give credit and make the answer CW.

Comment: @Gone sorry I didn't look at comments.

Answer (score 2):

Below put $\,p= p_{n+1},\ k = p_1\cdots p_n,\ a = 2$

**Lemma** $\ $ Prime $\,p\mid a^k+1\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a^2-1\ $ **if** $\ p\nmid a\,$ and $\,\color{#c00}{(k,p\!-\!1)=1}.\ $  **Proof:**

$\!\bmod p\!:\ (a^2)^k\equiv 1\equiv (a^2)^{p-1}\!\Rightarrow\, a^2\equiv 1\,$ by $\,a^2\,$ has order $\,j\!=\!1$, by $\,j\mid \color{#c00}{k,p\!-\!1\ \rm{coprimes}}$

Comment: We used little Fermat and the [Order Theorem:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) $\,c^m \equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm ord}(c)\mid m,\,$ which also yields a [slick proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7561/242) of the gcd result invoked in the arguments in the comments (repeated in the other answer).