# Finding homomorphism between congruences $\bmod 18$ and $\bmod 3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

The (cyclic) multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/18\mathbb{Z})^\times=\mathbb{Z}^\ast_{18}=\{1,5,7,11,13,17\}=<5>$ has an order $ord(\mathbb{Z}^\ast_{18})=6$ and based on Euler's theorem we can derive the following congruences from $5^j5^{6n+6-j}\equiv1\pmod{18}$:

\begin{array}{cc}
j=0 & [1]_{18}\cdot5^{6n+6}\equiv1\pmod{18}\\
j=1 & [5]_{18}\cdot5^{6n+5}\equiv1\pmod{18}\\
j=2 & [7]_{18}\cdot5^{6n+4}\equiv1\pmod{18}\\
j=3 & [17]_{18}\cdot5^{6n+3}\equiv1\pmod{18}\\
j=4 & [13]_{18}\cdot5^{6n+2}\equiv1\pmod{18}\\
j=5 & [11]_{18}\cdot5^{6n+1}\equiv1\pmod{18}\\
\end{array}

Now let us consider the following congruences:

\begin{array}{c}
[1]_{18}\cdot4\equiv1\pmod{3}\\
[5]_{18}\cdot8\equiv1\pmod{3}\\
[7]_{18}\cdot16\equiv1\pmod{3}\\
[17]_{18}\cdot2\equiv1\pmod{3}\\
[13]_{18}\cdot4\equiv1\pmod{3}\\
[11]_{18}\cdot2\equiv1\pmod{3}
\end{array}

Having in mind that, if $m\mid n$ (in our case $3\mid18$) the map $r\bmod n \rightarrow r\bmod m$ is a homomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times\rightarrow(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^\times$, what is the morphism between both congruences shown above - the one $\bmod{18}$ and the other one $\bmod3$? Maybe considering only the element $5$ as a generator of $\mathbb{Z}^\ast_{18}$ is not sufficient?

Comment: It boils down to $\, 5^6\equiv 1\pmod{18}\Rightarrow\, 5^6\equiv 1\pmod{3}.\,$ In fact $\bmod 3\!:\ 5^2\equiv (-1)^2\equiv 1\,$ so $6$ is not the *least* perriod, but the periodicy of length $6$ does persist.

Comment: Great! If we know that $\phi:\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z}$ with $\phi(r\bmod n)=r\bmod m$ is a ring homomorphism, then let's show that $\gcd(r\bmod n, n)=1$ leads to $\gcd(r\bmod m, m)=1$.

Comment: If $r$ is coprime to $n$ then it is also coprime to every factor $m$ of $n$ (by Euclid).

Comment: simply - that's it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If a natural number divides another, $m\mid n$, as in our case $3\mid18$, then for two integers $a,b$ the following implication holds:

\begin{equation}
 \label{eq:reduce_modulus}
 a\equiv b\pmod n\rightarrow a\equiv b\pmod m
\end{equation}

This means in our case $w\cdot5^{6n+6}\equiv 1\pmod{18}\rightarrow w\cdot5^{6n+6}\equiv 1\pmod 3$. Fundamentally we can state that $a\equiv b\pmod m$ implies $(a+m)\equiv b\pmod m$. Let us set $a=w\cdot2^{2n+2}$ and $b=1$ and $m=3$, then we obtain $(w\cdot2^{2n+2}+3)\equiv1\pmod3$ and using a factor $i\in\mathbb{N}$ we obtain the more general congruence $(w\cdot2^{2n+2}+3i)\equiv1\pmod3$. As a consequence the congruences are true, while $w\cdot5^{6n+6}=w\cdot2^{2n+2}+3i$ or rather while $3\mid(5^{6n+6}-2^{2n+2})$. These conditions continue $3\mid(5^{6n+5}-2^{2n+3})$ and $3\mid(5^{6n+4}-2^{2n+4})$ and so forth.

\begin{array}{llllll}
 j=0, & w\in [1]_{18} & \hspace{1em} w\cdot5^{6n+6}&\equiv1\pmod{18}&\hspace{4em}w\cdot2^{2n+2} &\equiv1\pmod{3}\\
 j=1, & w\in [5]_{18} & \hspace{1em} w\cdot5^{6n+5}&\equiv1\pmod{18}&\hspace{4em}w\cdot2^{2n+3} &\equiv1\pmod{3}\\
 j=2, & w\in [7]_{18} & \hspace{1em} w\cdot5^{6n+4}&\equiv1\pmod{18}&\hspace{4em}w\cdot2^{2n+4} &\equiv1\pmod{3}\\
 j=3, & w\in [17]_{18} & \hspace{1em} w\cdot5^{6n+3}&\equiv1\pmod{18}&\hspace{4em}w\cdot2^{2n+1} &\equiv1\pmod{3}\\
 j=4, & w\in [13]_{18} & \hspace{1em} w\cdot5^{6n+2}&\equiv1\pmod{18}&\hspace{4em}w\cdot2^{2n+2} &\equiv1\pmod{3}\\
 j=5, & w\in [11]_{18} & \hspace{1em} w\cdot5^{6n+1}&\equiv1\pmod{18}&\hspace{4em}w\cdot2^{2n+1} &\equiv1\pmod{3}
\end{array}