# Looking for a little help in understanding 'orders of elements'

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

I'm currently working through a proof where I need to prove that a group $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $\def\ord{\operatorname{ord}} H=\{g\in G \mid \ord(g) \text{ is a divisor of } 12\}$.  I already know that $G$ is commutative, and that the general structure to prove a given group is a subgroup of another by proving that it's closed under multiplication, has association, has an identity element, and has an inverse.  However, my main issue in proving this is a lack of understanding on the relationship that $\ord(g)$ has a divisor of $12$.

Any help in understanding the order of elements in context to this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: another way to describe $H$ is that $H = \{g \in G \mid g^{12}=e\}$.

Comment: What exactly do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: I'm trying to prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ using the rule above but I'm not sure how to write a proof with an order

Comment: Hint: apply the subgroup test using $\, g,h\in H\Rightarrow g^{12}=1=h^{12}\Rightarrow (g/h)^{12}=1\Rightarrow g/h\in H\ \ $

Comment: If you now understand it, please **delete the question since it is a duplicate**.

Comment: [Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) that $\,a^{12}=1\iff ord(a)\mid 12\ \ $