# $p_1^x\equiv p_2^x\equiv 1 \pmod{p_1p_2-1}$ problem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $p_1,p_2$ be primes and $x\in\mathbb{N}$. I want to investigate
\begin{equation*}
p_1^x\equiv p_2^x\equiv 1 \pmod{p_1p_2-1}
\end{equation*}
I want to find how $x$ depends on $p_1$ and $p_2$.

This is clearly something to do with the order of the primes but I can't find anything on comparing primes with the same order.

One way I thought to do this was to look at it as
\begin{equation*}
p_1^x-1\equiv p_2^x-1\equiv 0\pmod{p_1p_2-1}
\end{equation*}
and look at how their cyclotomic polynomials interact with each other, but cyclotomic polynomials don't really have any results for this.

For specific values this is easily evaluated. For example; $p_1=7$ and $p_2=11$, we get

\begin{equation*}
7^6=117649\equiv11^6\equiv1771561\equiv1\pmod{76}
\end{equation*}
so here $x=6$.

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: The equation holds for any two primes $p_1$ and $p_2$ with $x$ a multiple of $\varphi(p_1 p_2 - 1)$ where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

Comment: This is a direct result of Euler's theorem because $p_1$ and $p_1 p_2 - 1$ are always coprime.

Comment: In fact, you can generalise this fact to any two integers $m$ and $n$.

Comment: You can do better by taking $x$ to be a multiple of $\lambda(mn -1)$ where $\lambda$ is Charmichael's lambda function.

Comment: The smallest such $x$ is $\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord}_{mn-1}(n), \operatorname{ord}_{mn-1}(m))$ where $\operatorname{ord}_{a}(b)$ is the order of $b$ modulo $a$. That is the smallest integer $t$ such that $b^t \equiv 1 \pmod{a}$.

Comment: Use `\pmod{p_1p_2-1}` to get the parenthetical mod operator.

Comment: Thank you @Oussema for your responses. I hadn't noticed that $p_1$ and $p_1p_2-1$ were coprime, that's great! I will look into Charmichael's Lambda function. 

I am mainly looking at primes, though you're right this can be generalised to any intergers $m$ and $n$.

Comment: And thank you @ArturoMagidin I didn't know that piece of code - that will absolutely help for my write up too...

Answer (score 1):

$\!\!\bmod p_1 p_2\! -\!1\!:\,\ p_1 p_2\equiv 1\Rightarrow p_2\equiv p_1^{-1}\,$ so $\,p_1^n\!\equiv\! 1\iff  p_2^n\equiv 1,\,$ so your question boils down to finding the order of $p_1$ (= order of $p_2),\,$ [necessarily](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) a divisor of every $n$ such that $\,p_1^n\equiv 1\,$ (e.g. the order must divide the Euler phi and Carmichael lambda function of the modulus).