# Problem understanding the proof of Pocklington's criterion

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a problem in the proof of the Pocklington criteria. The theorem itself is
[image]

Now I have this proof (my question concerns a point in the last three lines):

[image]

My question is:
So we choose $p$ to be a prime divisor $n$.
So $\varphi(p) = p-1$.
I know that $a^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$.
Now the proof says that by euler's totient theorem we can deduce $r\mid p-1$.
But I do not understand why. Shouldn't we assume that $p$ and $a$ coprime to deduce this?

Comment: $a^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}\Rightarrow p\nmid a,\,$ so $\, a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}\Rightarrow r:= {\rm ord}_p(a)\mid p-1\,$ by [Corollary$_1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) in linked dupe.