# Order of an Element in $\Bbb Z_p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a very simple question & would appreciate it very much if you could assist.

Let $n$ be an odd positive composite integer and let $p$ be a prime divisor of $n$, where $p$ is not  of the form $p= 2^m +1, m \geq 1$. Let $a \in \mathbb Z_{p} -\{0\}$. Further, let $r$ be the order of $a$ (i.e. $a^r \equiv 1 \bmod{p}$).

Show that if $a^n \equiv a \pmod{n}$, then

1. the integer $r$ divides $n-1$.
2. $r$ is not a power of two (i.e. $r\not= 2^j$ for some $j\geq 1$). Note that $n$ is a composite integer. For prime $n$, it easy to find examples in which the order is a power of two: $2^{16} \equiv 1 \pmod{257},~2^{64} \equiv 1 \pmod{641}.$

I tried the following.

Since  $a^n\equiv a \pmod{n} \Longrightarrow 
a^{n}\equiv a\pmod{p}$, it follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
a^{n}& \equiv & (a^{p})^\frac{n}{p} \pmod{p},\\
&\equiv & a^\frac{n}{p}  \pmod{p},\\
&\equiv & a^{(k_1(p-1)+k_2)}  \pmod{p},\\
&\equiv & a^{k_2} \equiv a \pmod{p},
\end{eqnarray*}
for some positive integers $k_1$ and $k_2$.

Further,
\begin{eqnarray*}
a^{n}&\equiv & a^{k_2} \equiv a \pmod{p},\\
a^{n-1}&\equiv & a^{k_2-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p},
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, I know that $r|(k_2-1)$. Does this imply  that $r|(n-1)$?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: the first question can be answered only by reading the definition of order

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace It's certainly an easy consequence of the definition, but it doesn't follow immediately from it.

Comment: @jjagmath it depends on the definition you choose :)

Comment: What is part 2 asking? Certainly you can find an element of order a power of $2$. Just take $(-1)^2\equiv_p 1$

Comment: $(1)$ follows since $a^n\equiv a$ also holds mod $p\mid n$ so $a^{n-1}\equiv 1$ by scaling by $a^{-1}$ ($a\not\equiv 0$ since $a^r\equiv 1)$ so $r\mid n-1$ by the [Order Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242). $(2)$ is false, e.g. $a=-1$ is a counterexample as mentioned. Please polish your questions *before* posting them.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**:

1. You can assume that $n-1>r$, otherwise there is nothing to prove. Now write $$n-1=qr+s$$ and consider $a^{n-1}\equiv_p 1$. What can you say about $s$?

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).