# Showing that $m = 2^{15} -1$ is not prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Here is the question:
Let $m=2^{15}−1=32767$. Show that

(a) The order of $2$ modulo $m$ is $15$.

(b) $15$ does not divide $m − 1$. Why does this imply that $m$ is not prime?

I have shown that the order of $2$ modulo $m$ is $15$, and that $15$ does not divide $m-1$. However, I am struggling with showing why this implies that $m$ is not prime. Can anybody provide any hints? I have tried to use Euler's Theorem to no avail.

Comment: prime $m = 2^{15}\!-1\overset{\rm Fermat}\Rightarrow \bmod m\!:\ 2^{\:\!\large\color{#c00}{m-1}}\!\equiv 1\Rightarrow  {\rm ord_m}(2)\!=\!15\mid \color{#c00}{m\!-\!1}\,$ by [Corollary$_1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) in the linked dupe. $\ \ $

Comment: For $~a,k \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ you have that $~\left(x^a - 1\right)~$ divides $~\left(x^{ak} - 1\right).$

Answer (score 2):

If $m$ were prime, then the multiplicative group $G=(\Bbb Z/m \Bbb Z)^{\ast}$ would have order $m-1$.  You have shown that $2$ is an element of $G$ with order $15$, so $15 \mid \vert G \vert$.  Since you also have shown that $15 \nmid (m-1)$, that means $\vert G \vert \neq m-1$, which in turn means $m$ can't be prime.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).