# non-perfect square of number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$a^{1/2}$ is either an integer or an irrational number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/a1-2-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number)

I would like to know the better proof for the following one.

question: non perfect square of any integer is an irrational. I given my answer at below. But I need better method. If any one can provide, I am very grateful to them.

my answer is: x=sqrt(2) is irratioonal by
looking at x+1 and x-1. Then (x+1)(x-1)=1 and x-1=a/b gives
a/b+2=b/a, so that (a+2b)/b=b/a. Without loss of generality (a,b)=1 and
then also (a+2b,b)=1 and the conclusion (Euclid VII.20) is that a+2b=b,
b=a, which gives a=b=0, a contradiction.

We can use a similar idea, although we won't be able to use reciprocals,
generally. Suppose sqrt(n) is rational.
Then for any a/b ((a,b)=1), sqrt(n)-a/b=c/d is rational, where w.l.o.g.
(c,d)=1, d>0.
We get c/d+2a/b=n-a^2/b^2.
So cb^2=d(nb^2-a^2-2ab). Now b^2|RHS, but b^2 is coprime to nb^2-2ab-a^2,
since any prime factor of b^2 is a prime factor of b and hence also of
nb^2-2ab. If it were also of nb^2-2ab-a^2, then it would divide a^2 and
hence a, contrary to (a,b)=1.
Thus we have b^2|d. Write d=b^2r.
Then c=r(nb^2-a^2-2ab). Now any prime factor of r divides c. Since r|d and
(c,d)=1, r is a unit. Since d>0 and b^2>0, r>0. So r=1.
Then d=b^2.
So sqrt(n)=a/b+c/b^2=(ab+c)/b^2. Choosing a/b=0/1, sqrt(n)=c, an integer,
so that n=c^2 is the square of an integer.
Thus, if n is not a square, then sqrt(n) is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

If any rational number is squared; you have two cases, if it's an integer, then its square is a perfect square. Otherwise, you need to prove that its square is not an integer, and then you're done.