# If $p_1,...,p_n$ are positive prime numbers then $\sqrt{p_1\cdots p_n} \notin \Bbb{Q}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

We want to proove that:

> If $p_1,...,p_n$ are positive, distinct, prime numbers then
>   $\sqrt{p_1\cdots p_n} \notin \Bbb{Q}$.

Let's assume that $\sqrt{p_1\cdots p_n} \in \Bbb{Q}$. Then, $\exists (a,b)\in \mathbb{Z^*\times Z^*}:\sqrt{p_1\cdots p_n}=\frac{a}{b}$ with $\gcd (a,b)=1.$ So, $a^2=p_1\cdots p_n \cdot b^2. $ But how do we continue? Is this technique right or should we follow something different?

*PS: This is a part [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1230181/326865) proof, and I would like to discuss it.*

Thank you.

Comment: $p_1$ appears with odd exponent in the right-hand side, but with even exponent in the left-hand side.

Comment: @Chris  See each of the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189130/prove-that-if-n-is-not-the-square-of-a-natural-number-then-sqrtn-is-irra or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/sqrt-a-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of the one indicated. The one indicated states "an integer or an irrational number", this one "$\notin \mathbb{Q}$". So, any answer should also show $\sqrt{p_1...p_n}$ is not an integer. I also was confused by this subtlety ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic proof that $\sqrt 2 \notin \Bbb Q$ readily extends to this case, to wit:

if

$\sqrt{p_1p_2 . . . p_n} = \dfrac{a}{b} \tag 1$

with $a, b \in \Bbb N$, $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, then

$p_1p_2 \ldots p_n b^2 = a^2, \tag 2$

whence $p_1 \mid a^2$; thus $p_1 \mid a$ and so $a = p_1c$; thus

$a^2 = p_1^2c^2 = p_1p_2 \ldots p_n b^2, \tag 3$

whence

$p_1c^2 = p_2p_3 \ldots p_n b^2; \tag 4$

since the $p_i$ are distinct, we must have $p_1 \mid b^2$, whence $p_1 \mid b$, contradicting our assumption that $\gcd(a, b) = 1$.

I think the ancient roots or this proof are worthy or respect, and I also note the method readily extends to show many similar propositions hold.

I presented this answer because it seems to me that the linked proof is pretty complex for this *particular* problem, although it is certainly engaging in and of itself, and leads in entaging directions.

Comment: Thank you for this clear proof. I 'm sure this will help and the other proof (which I linked) above.

Comment: You should justify the *fundamental* claim that prime $\,p\mid a^2\Rightarrow\,p\mid a.\ $

Answer (score 2):

Hint: think about the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$, and note that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ implies that they do not share any prime factors. Use this to show that $a^2 = p_1 \cdots p_n b^2$ cannot happen.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Let's assume that $a={a_1}^{n_1}\cdots {a_k}^{n_k}$ and $b={b_1}^{m_1}\cdots {b_l}^{m_l}$ are the prime factorazations of $a,b$ respectively. So, ${a_1}^{2n_1} \cdots {a_k}^{2n_k}=p_1 \cdots p_n \cdot {b_1}^{2m_1} \cdots {b_l}^{2m_l}$ where $a_i\neq b_j \forall i,j$. Now? Does this help?

Comment: @Chris Yes you are almost there. Now use the hint given by the other answerers/commenters: since $a_i \ne b_j$ for all $i,j$, it must be that one of the $a_i$ is $p_1$. But the exponent of $p_1$ on the right-hand side is odd while the exponents on the left-hand side are all even.

Comment: So, you say that $\exists i\in \{1,...,k  \}: a_i=p_1$. But, from this $2n_i=1$, contradiction. Right?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the factorization of $q^2$ for some $q \in \mathbb Q$, you will see that all the prime powers are indeed even. In your case, they're not, hence there is no rational square root.

Comment: Worth emphasis: the above hint implicitly uses the **Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic,** i.e. existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations of integers $\neq 0.\,$ In any complete rigorous proof, we should *explicitly* mention any use of such properties (or closely related properties such as Euclid's or Bezout's Lemma), esp. when one is first learning these matters.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if wrong:

gcd(a,b)=1:

Assume :

$ a^2= p_1 p_2p_3 .....p_n b^2$.

$\rightarrow$  $p_1$ divides $a^2$;

$\rightarrow$ $p_1$ divides $a,$ by the Theorem below

$ \rightarrow$  $ (p_1)^2$ divides $a^2$.

Likewise

$(p_2)^2,(p_3)^2.,.....,(p_n)^2$ divide  $a^2$.

Hence:

$a^2 =$

$(p_1p_2p_3......p_n)^2 q^2 =$

$p_1p_2p_3.....p_n b^2$;

$\rightarrow$ $ b^2 = p_1p_2p_3...p_n q^2$

$\rightarrow$ $p_1,p_2,p_3,....,p_ n$ divide $b^2$;

$\rightarrow$  $p_1,p_2,p_3,....,p_n$ divide $ b$ by the Theorem below.

Hence $p_1,p_2,p_3,.....,p_n$ are common divisors of $a$ and $b$,

in contradiction to the assumption

gcd$(a,b) =1$.

$ $

Used: Theorem of Number Theory:

If $p$ is a prime and $p$ | $ab$, then

$p$ | $a$ or $p$ | $b$.

It follows: If $p$ | $a^2$ then $p$ | $a$.

Comment: You should justify the *fundamental* claim that prime $\,p\mid a^2\Rightarrow\,p\mid a.\ $

Comment: Bill. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Reading further there are a couple more significant gaps. You need to *justify* the claims that  $\,p_i^3\mid a^2 \,\Rightarrow\, m := p_1^2\cdots p_n^2\mid a^2.\,$ Also needing justifcation is the claim that $\,a^2/m = q^2$ is the square of an *integer*. Both proofs depend crucially on *special* properties of the ring of integers that are not generally true for other number systems, so such properties should be *explicitly* invoked when that are employed.

Comment: Bill. Thank you for pointing out weak points.Attempt to remedy: p_1 | a, then a = r× p_1. Now p_2 | a then p_2 divides r or p_1. Since p_2 does not divide p_1, it divides r, I.e. r = s× p_2, or a = s× p_1 p_2 . p_3 | a ,  p_3 | s, or p_3 | (p_1p_2) .p_3 does not divide (p_1p_2) , hence divides s .Continuing we get a= q× p_1p_2...p_n. Then a^2 = q^2× (p_1)^2 (p_2 )^2...(p_n)^2, [hence (p_1)^2(p_2)^2...(p_n)^2 , the product, divides a^2]. Kindly let me know, thanks again, Peter.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth mentioning [Rational root theorem (RRT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). From $$\sqrt{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} p_i}=x \Rightarrow x^2 - \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} p_i=0 \tag{1}$$
which is a polynomial with integer coefficients, leading coefficient is $1$, thus $x$, the solution, can only be integer or irrational. Let's assume it's an integer, then (from the same RRT) it should divide the constant term $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} p_i$ or $\gcd\left(x,\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} p_i \right)=x$. Then either $x$ is a prime $p_k$ or divisible by such a prime, in both cases $p_k \mid x$ and $p_k \mid \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} p_i$. Using [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) we will conclude that $p_k \in \{p_1,p_2,...,p_n\}$ and from $(1)$ $$p_k \mid \prod\limits_{i=1,i\ne k}^{n} p_i$$
which, from the same Euclid's lemma, is not possible.

Comment: There is a big gap: RRT implies only that any rational root is an integer. To complete the proof you need to *prove* it has no integer roots (which requires using *strong* properties of integer arithmetic).

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, I missed that gap. Fixed now with just $\gcd$ and Euclid Lemma.

Answer (score 1):

A ready consequence of Fundamental theorem of arithematic is that *A perfect square must have even powers of primes*. Since all the primes are coprime with each other so there is no chance for thing in you square root to be a perfect square since every prime will have an odd power $(1)$

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat different result
is that
if $n$ is not a perfect square
then $\sqrt{n}$
is irrational.

Here is one of the many proofs:
[Follow-up Question: Proof of Irrationality of $\sqrt{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391411/follow-up-question-proof-of-irrationality-of-sqrt3/1391466#1391466)

Of course you
then have to show that
$\prod p_i$
is not a perfect square.