# Are all the square roots of non-square numbers surds?

Tags: square-numbers

Quite self explanatory really, basically, are $\sqrt5 ,\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt7 $ and surds?
(So basically, every square root of any non-square number)

Comment: @usr93945 I don't think you're asking what you want to ask. If a number isn't a square number, then by its very definition it is surd.

Comment: That's all I wanted to know :)

Comment: Do you mean to ask "is the square root of a non-square integer irrational"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I believe that's what he wants to ask, but he hasn't realised so yet.

Comment: If that is the question you mean to ask, then [it has an answer here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/sqrt-a-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number)

Comment: I always wondered if non-surd numbers were called absurd numbers.