# Square numbers multiplied by non-square numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

> If you multiply a square number with a non square number, the result is never a square number.

Here, a square number is product of an integer with itself.

Do you agree with this statement? If so, explain why.  If you disagree with this statement, please give me an counterexample where the answer is a square number.

Comment: What kind of "numbers" are we talking here?

Comment: @fkraiem What are you thinking here? I can't think of any reasonable definition of "numbers" where the answer would make a difference.

Comment: I agree with this statement, because it is true.

Comment: I suspect [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708827/square-number-multiplied-by-non-square-numbers) is a duplicate

Comment: @MJD The answer, maybe. The "explanation", maybe not.

Comment: @user135034, have you looked at the link I provided? It's the exact same question!

Comment: I guess there is another link, thank you for notifying me.

Comment: @MJD One should think a little bit harder, e.g. in $\,\Bbb Z[\sqrt{12}]\,$ we have $\, 3\cdot 2^2 = \sqrt{12}^2$ therefore **the product of a nonsquare and a square is a square** for some  quadratic *numbers*.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks!

Comment: @MJD Thanks.  TIP: one can often find counterexamples like these in simple quadratic number rings that lack unique factorization.

Comment: How come literally no one even thought about, or at least mentioned, the edge case ($0$ times any nonsquare equals $0 = 0^2$ is a square)?

Answer (score 3):

Using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic we can see if $a^2=b$ and the prime factorization of $a$ is $2^{a_2}\cdot3^{a_3}\cdot5^{a_3} \dots$ then the prime factorization of $a^2$ is $2^{2a_2}\cdot3^{2a_3}\cdot5^{2a_3} \dots$ So this tells us the prime factorization of squares has even exponents. Let k be a square and m a non-square. Then $mk$ has some odd exponents and therefore is not a square.

Comment: This answer has the right idea, however the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) is not the theorem you are thinking of.

Comment: (You're looking for this [ostentatiously-named theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic))

Comment: Oh, of course, thanks for pointing it out. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It follows easily be the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, but it can be done with weaker tools. Namely if for integers $\, a^2 = b^2 c \,$ for a nonsquare $\,c\,$ then $\,x^2 - c\,$ has a rational root $\,x = a/b\,$ so, by the Rational Root Test, $\,a/b = d\,$ is an integer, so $\, c = (a/b)^2 = d^2,\,$ contra hypothesis.

**Remark** $\ $ As above, the problem is equivalent to the standard irrationality proofs of square-roots, about which there are many prior threads here, e.g. [this one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4467/242)

Note that this property may fail for other numbers, e.g. in $\,\Bbb Z[\sqrt{12}]\,$ we have $\, 3\cdot 2^2 = \sqrt{12}^2$ therefore **the product of a nonsquare and a square is a square** for some  quadratic *numbers*. Thus any proof must necessarily employ some property special to the ring of integers, in particular, some property not shared by all quadratic number rings, e.g. unique factorization; Euclid's Lemma.