# Suppose $x$ and $y$ are integers and $x^2$ is a multiple of $y^2$. Is $x$ necessarily a multiple of $y$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Suppose $x$ and $y$ are integers and $x^2$ is a multiple of $y^2$. Is $x$ necessarily a multiple of $y$?

Came across this question as part of a homework set. I tried the following:
Suppose $x^2 \,\vert\, y^2$, then $x^2$ $=$ $ky^2$ for some k. Taking square roots on both sides, we end up with $x$ $=$ $\pm$$(\sqrt{k})$$y$.

However, I am unsure of how to proceed from this point. I believe we either need to prove or disprove the fact that $\sqrt{k}$ is an integer value for all values of $k$ but the method eludes me.

Comment: Hint:  Consider the prime factorizations of $x,y$.

Comment: If $x^2|y^2$ then $y^2=kx^2$, not the other way around.  It doesn't change the argument.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Divide the equation $x^2=ky^2$ by the square of the gcd of $x,y$. You get $X^2=kY^2$ where $X,Y$ are coprime.

Then prove that this equation is only possible if $k$ is a square.

You can finally conclude that $x^2$ is a multiple of $y^2$ if and only if $x$ is a multiple of $y$.

Answer (score 0):

If there exists some integer $d$ such that $x^2=dy^2$, I claim there is some integer $k$ such that $k^2=d$. [The claim is proved here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709948/square-numbers-multiplied-by-non-square-numbers).

So, $x=ky$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $k$ is not a square, is $\sqrt ky$ an integer?