# $a^n\mid b^n$ if and only if $a\mid b$.

Tags: divisibility

Suppose $a$, $b$, $n$ are positive. Prove that $a^n\mid b^n$ if and only if $a\mid b$.

I know that this can be proved through prime factorization, but I want to prove it using other methods.
I understand that the if and only if statement requires you to prove the two cases:


1. If $a^n\mid b^n$ then $a\mid b$.

2. If $a\mid b$ then $a^n\mid b^n$.

but I have no idea on how to approach it.

Comment: Can you at least do one of the directions?

Comment: In other words: (2) follows by a direct application of the definitions.

Comment: +1 with Henning.  I'll wait before giving out the answer, but will remind you the definitions of divisibility which will hopefully give you ideas on how to set it up.  Remember that $a|b$ means that $b = ak$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.  As for proving the first direction, try proof by contrapositive.

Comment: You might find this intresting http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/sqrt-a-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number

Answer (score 2):

$a|b \ :\Leftrightarrow \exists k\in\mathbb{N} : k \cdot a = b$

1.)
$$a^n|b^n \ \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ b^n = \hat{k} \cdot a^n $$

$$\sqrt[n]{\hat{k}} = \frac{b}{a}$$

Since $a,b$ are positive integers, $\frac{b}{a} \in \mathbb{Q}$. For $n>1$, the $n$-th root of a positive non-zero rational number is either an integer or irrational, but in this case it cannot be irrational because the RHS is rational. Therefore, $k' := \sqrt[n]{\hat{k}} \in \mathbb{N}$ and $b = k' \cdot a$, thus $a|b$.

2.) 
$$a|b \ \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ b = k \cdot a \ \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ b^n = k^n \cdot a^n \ \ \ \Rightarrow a^n | b^n$$
because $k^n \in \mathbb{N}$.

P.S.: The approach for 1.) is beating around the bush, you should really use the prime factorization as the main argument.

Comment: You need to be careful: $4 \mid -16$ and $-16 = -4 \cdot 4$. But taking the square root of $-4$ does not work here.

Comment: furthermore, the first root of $\frac{1}{2}$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ which is neither an integer nor irrational, so your statement is invalid.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think it's clear that he meant non-trivial roots.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Question starts with "Suppose a, b, n are positive" :)

Comment: @JMoravitz Of course $n>1$ is implicitly assumed because the claim for $n=1$ is trivial

Comment: @GDumphart ah so it does. Perhaps you should replace $k \in \mathbb Z$ with $k \in \mathbb N$ in your answer.

Comment: Haha leave me alone with the $n = 1$ case.

Comment: @Mathmo123 True, I'll do that. Thank you.