# Prove that if n is a natural number and if n has a rational square root then in fact the square root of n is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$n = (\frac{a}{b})^2$, where $a$ and $b$ have no common divisors. This yields

$nb^2 = a^2$

$ra^2b^2 = a^2$ (because $n = ra^2$)

I don't understand why $n$ is equal to $ra^2$.

Comment: Where is $r$ introduced?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/4467/131263.

Comment: Because $n$ must divide $a^2$ and this is a consequence of $(a,b)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Since n is an integer, so is $({a\over b})^2$. There are two possibilities:

1) ${a\over b}$ is an irrational number which is not possible.

2) ${a\over b}$ is a rational number. Therefore it is an integer because $({a\over b})^2$ is. Since ${a\over b}$ is an integer, there is some $q\in \mathbb Z$ such that $a=b.q$. Hence $n=q^2$.