# Examples of proofs of irrationality without using contradiction

Tags: number-theory, alternative-proof, rationality-testing

I'm just wondering if there exists proofs that certain numbers are irrational that do not begin by saying some like along the lines of "assume $k=a/b$ for integers $a$ and $b$" and then deduce a contradiction. My question is, are there any irrationality proofs out there that somehow prove irrationality directly or do they all somehow utilize proof by contradiction?

Comment: You need a "direct definition" of irrationality for that. An irrational number is (by definition) a number which is not rational, so in order to prove that a number is irrational you must prove it's not rational.

Comment: Another example is the proof by contradiction of Euclid's theorem that there are infinitely many primes, which deduces a contradiction from the hypothesis that there are finitely many primes. So an analogous question to yours is: can you prove that a set is infinite without a proof by contradiction by assuming that it is finite? If infinite $:=$ not finite, like irrational $ :=$ not rational, then you may face the same hurdles.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the polynomial $x^2-2$, by Eisenstein's criterion this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. It follows that the extension degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $2$, hence strict. This shows that $\sqrt{2}\notin \mathbb{Q}$.

You can go through the proofs of Eisenstein's criterion and the other theory involved, we nowhere use that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:** I remember coming across a real neat generalized way of proving the irrationality of $\sqrt{a}$ in the *American Mathematical Monthly* (credit due to Amrik Singh Nimbran). Maybe the following will be something along the lines of what you are looking for (Daniel Escudero's comment makes a good point though):

**Generalized proof:** Let $a$ be a square-free positive integer and $[\sqrt{a}]=b$. where $[\;]$ denotes the greatest integer contained in the square root. Then $b^2<(\sqrt{a})^2<(b+1)^2$. Thus, $a$ lies between two consecutive squares; hence, $\sqrt{a}$ is not an integer. Suppose that $\sqrt{a}$ is rational, i.e., $\sqrt{a}=\frac{m}{n}, 1<n<m<(b+1)n; m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Using a division algorithm, we may write the following: $m=bn+r, n>r, r\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence, $\sqrt{a}=\frac{bn+r}{n}$. Let $g=(n,r)$. So, $n=gs$ and $r=gt, s>t, (s,t)=1; g,s,t\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\sqrt{a}=\frac{bs+t}{s}$. Hence
$$
(a-b^2)s^2=t(2bs+t).\tag{1}
$$
Since $t\mid(t(2bs+t))$ and $(s,t)=1$, either $(a-b^2)=tu, u\in\mathbb{N}$, or $t=1$. In the first case, we would have $s(us-2b)=t\Rightarrow s\mid t$, which is impossible for $s>t$. In the second case, that is, $t=1$, we obtain
$$
s\{(a-b^2)s-2b\}=1.\tag{2}
$$
Equation $(4)\Rightarrow s\mid 1\Rightarrow s=1$, which contradicts our supposition that $s>t=1$. Further, it leads to $a=(b+1)^2$, contradicting our supposition $a<(b+1)^2$. Hence, $\sqrt{a}$ is irrational. $\blacksquare$

Comment: This is a nice elegant proof, but you still do say "suppose that $\sqrt(a)$ is irrational". I'm starting to think that what I'm looking for is inherently impossible

Comment: @ASKASK That is why I prefaced the proof with a comment--to let you know that the assumption/contradiction will still be used. Perhaps I could have been clearer, but I thought maybe it would still prove somewhat useful as it is somewhat different than how most proofs start.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it's possible. If you explicitly state and explain this (rephrase the comment) then I'll give you the check

Comment: @ASKASK I can rephrase it, but it is really due to Daniel's comment. I simply wanted to provide a nice way of going about proving the irrationality of a number in general that has a bit of a different "flavor" than what you generally encounter. An answer check may not be appropriate since my answer *really* doesn't answer your question.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question. There are much shorter ways to prove irrationality of sqrts using only the division algorithm, e.g. [this one,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/4491/242) which could be shortened further if everything was inlined (at the cost of obscuring conceptual structure).

Comment: @ASKASK Here is a another shorter proof. $\tag*{}$
${\bf Theorem}\ \ $ If $\ x = \sqrt{n}\ $ is is rational then it is an integer.

Comment: $\begin{align}& {\bf Proof}\ \ {\rm Deny,\ \,so}\,\ \ \overbrace{ x = \frac{a}b}^{\Large\color{#c00}{bx\, =\, a}},\ \ {\rm and}\,\ \  \color{#b0f}{b\nmid a}\,\ {\rm by}\,\ x\not\in\Bbb Z. {\rm \ wlog}\,\ b\ \,{\rm is}\ \,\color{#0a0}{\rm least}\ {\rm denom}\\
&\color{#c00}ax\, =\, (\color{#c00}{bx})x =\, bn.\ \ a = qb+r,\,\ \color{#b0f}{0 < r} < b\ \ \text{by the Division Algorithm}\\ 
&rx\! =\! (a\!-\!q\color{#c00}b)\color{#c00}x\! =\! bn\!-\!q\color{#c00}a =: k\,\Rightarrow\, x = \frac{k}r,\,\ \text{contra }\,b\,\text{ is the $\color{#0a0}{\rm least}$ denom}\end{align}$ $\tag*{}$